# Динамичная граница в форме волны

Tags: javascript, html, html5, анимация, математика

Есть кое-что, что мне нужно построить, но мои математические способности не на должном уровне.

То, что я хочу построить, выглядит что-то вроде [этого демо](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-colorful-wave-effect/), но мне нужно, чтобы это был гибрид круга и многоугольника вместо линии.

Черная линия, которая в основном действует как граница на странице, должна быть динамичной и генерироваться случайным образом.
В настоящее время я переношу [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54051068/7543162) с целью, как я надеюсь, получить решение, но у меня есть серьезные сомнения, что я смогу это выяснить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Есть идеи, как это сделать, или кто-нибудь может объяснить математику?**

Ниже приведены мои заметки о коде из ответа, который я указал выше.

```js
var
  cw = cvs.width = window.innerWidth,
  ch = cvs.height = window.innerHeight,
  cx = cw / 2,
  cy = ch / 2,
  xs = Array(),
  ys = Array(),
  npts = 20,
  amplitude = 87, // can be val from 1 to 100
  frequency = -2, // can be val from -10 to 1 in steps of 0.1

ctx.lineWidth = 4

// creates array of coordinates that
// divides page into regular portions
// creates array of weights
for (var i = 0; i < npts; i++) {
  xs[i] = (cw/npts)*i
  ys[i] = 2.0*(Math.random()-0.5)*amplitude
}

function Draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.beginPath();

  for (let x = 0; x < cw; x++) {
    y = 0.0
    wsum = 0.0

    for (let i = -5; i <= 5; i++) {
      xx = x; // 0 / 1 / 2 / to value of screen width

      // creates sequential sets from [-5 to 5] to [15 to 25]
      ii = Math.round(x/xs[1]) + i

      // `xx` is a sliding range with the total value equal to client width
      // keeps `ii` within range of 0 to 20
      if (ii < 0) {
        xx += cw
        ii += npts
      }
      if (ii >= npts){
        xx -= cw
        ii -= npts
      }

      // selects eleven sequential array items
      // which are portions of the screen width and height
      // to create staggered inclines in increments of those portions
      w = Math.abs(xs[ii] - xx)

      // creates irregular arcs
      // based on the inclining values
      w = Math.pow(w, frequency)

      // also creates irregular arcs therefrom
      y += w*ys[ii];

      // creates sets of inclining values
      wsum += w;

    }

    // provides a relative position or weight
    // for each y-coordinate in the total path
    y /= wsum;

    //y = Math.sin(x * frequency) * amplitude;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y+cy); 
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
Draw();
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Dynamic Wavy Path/Border](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54164738/7394871) от участника  [@oldboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7543162/oldboy).</sub>

Comment: @ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54164738/7394871

Comment: если уж это перевод - не могли бы Вы и комментарии в коде перевести?

Comment: @Дмытрык без проблем:) ответ переведу, вопрос переводить нет смысла

Answer (score 7):

Это мой ответ. Пожалуйста, прочитайте комментарии в коде.
Я надеюсь, что это то, что вам нужно.

```js
// инициировать  canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = (canvas.width = 600),
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = (canvas.height = 400),
  cy = ch / 2;
ctx.fillStyle = "white"

// определить углы прямоугольника
let corners = [[100, 100], [500, 100], [500, 300], [100, 300]];

let amplitud = 20;// амплитуда колебаний
let speed = 0.01;// скорость колебаний
let points = []; // массив точек для рисования кривой

class Point {
  constructor(x, y, hv) {
    // точка колеблется вокруг этой точки (cx, cy)
    this.cx = x;
    this.cy = y;
    // текущий угол колебаний
    this.a = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
    this.hv = hv;// переменная, чтобы знать, является ли колебание горизонтальным или вертикальным

    this.update();
  }

  // функция для обновления значения угла
  update() {
    this.a += speed;

    if (this.hv == 0) {
      this.x = this.cx;
      this.y = this.cy + amplitud * Math.cos(this.a);
    } else {
      this.x = this.cx + amplitud * Math.cos(this.a);
      this.y = this.cy;
    }
  }
}


// функция, чтобы разделить линию, которая идет от a до b в n сегментах
// Я использую полученные точки, чтобы создать новый точечный объект и вставить эту новую точку в массив точек
function divide(n, a, b) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    let p = {
      x: (b[0] - a[0]) * i / n + a[0],
      y: (b[1] - a[1]) * i / n + a[1],
      hv: b[1] - a[1]
    };
    points.push(new Point(p.x, p.y, p.hv));
  }
}

divide(10, corners[0], corners[1]);points.pop();
divide(5, corners[1], corners[2]);points.pop();
divide(10, corners[2], corners[3]);points.pop();
divide(5, corners[3], corners[0]);points.pop();


// это функция, которая берет массив точек и рисует изогнутую линию через эти точки
function drawCurves() {
  //найти первую середину и перейти к ней
  let p = {};
  p.x = (points[points.length - 1].x + points[0].x) / 2;
  p.y = (points[points.length - 1].y + points[0].y) / 2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
  //кривой через остальное, останавливаясь в каждой средней точке
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
    let mp = {};
    mp.x = (points[i].x + points[i + 1].x) / 2;
    mp.y = (points[i].y + points[i + 1].y) / 2;
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(points[i].x, points[i].y, mp.x, mp.y);
  }
  //кривая через последнюю точку, обратно к первой средней точке
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
    points[points.length - 1].x,
    points[points.length - 1].y,
    p.x,
    p.y
  );
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
}

function Draw() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(Draw);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  points.map(p => {
    p.update();
  });
  drawCurves();
}

Draw();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid; background:#6ab150}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54170317/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>