# Как библиотека анимирует каплю svg?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, svg-animation

Как библиотека анимирует каплю как на рисунке, если где пример?
На рисунке ниже зелёное  пятно, которое изменяет свои контуры.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это состояния капли на картинках  состояние 1
 состояние 2

Comment: Я вот про зеленное пятно ,которое деформируется

Comment: Да какая библиотека  с SVG таокое делает,если пример?

Comment: вот на сайте что,то подобное https://jolien.ru/job/

Comment: Если такое на код пен?

Comment: Можно подробней?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Oleksandr07/pen/gvXyEm

Comment: Вопрос еще актуальный  еще

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Как библиотека анимирует каплю вот так,если где пример?

Есть скрипт, изменяя параметры которого можно получить интересные эффекты плавного перетекания из одной формы в другую.

```js
// инициировать  canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = (canvas.width = 600),
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = (canvas.height = 400),
  cy = ch / 2;
ctx.fillStyle = "white"

// определить углы прямоугольника
let corners = [[100, 100], [500, 100], [500, 300], [100, 300]];

let amplitud = 20;// амплитуда колебаний
let speed = 0.01;// скорость колебаний
let points = []; // массив точек для рисования кривой

class Point {
  constructor(x, y, hv) {
    // точка колеблется вокруг этой точки (cx, cy)
    this.cx = x;
    this.cy = y;
    // текущий угол колебаний
    this.a = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
    this.hv = hv;// переменная, чтобы знать, является ли колебание горизонтальным или вертикальным

    this.update();
  }

  // функция для обновления значения угла
  update() {
    this.a += speed;

    if (this.hv == 0) {
      this.x = this.cx;
      this.y = this.cy + amplitud * Math.cos(this.a);
    } else {
      this.x = this.cx + amplitud * Math.cos(this.a);
      this.y = this.cy;
    }
  }
}


// функция, чтобы разделить линию, которая идет от a до b в n сегментах
// Я использую полученные точки, чтобы создать новый точечный объект и вставить эту новую точку в массив точек
function divide(n, a, b) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    let p = {
      x: (b[0] - a[0]) * i / n + a[0],
      y: (b[1] - a[1]) * i / n + a[1],
      hv: b[1] - a[1]
    };
    points.push(new Point(p.x, p.y, p.hv));
  }
}

divide(10, corners[0], corners[1]);points.pop();
divide(5, corners[1], corners[2]);points.pop();
divide(10, corners[2], corners[3]);points.pop();
divide(5, corners[3], corners[0]);points.pop();

// это функция, которая берет массив точек и рисует изогнутую линию через эти точки
function drawCurves() {
  //найти первую середину и перейти к ней
  let p = {};
  p.x = (points[points.length - 1].x + points[0].x) / 2;
  p.y = (points[points.length - 1].y + points[0].y) / 2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
  //кривой через остальное, останавливаясь в каждой средней точке
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
    let mp = {};
    mp.x = (points[i].x + points[i + 1].x) / 2;
    mp.y = (points[i].y + points[i + 1].y) / 2;
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(points[i].x, points[i].y, mp.x, mp.y);
  }
  //кривая через последнюю точку, обратно к первой средней точке
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
    points[points.length - 1].x,
    points[points.length - 1].y,
    p.x,
    p.y
  );
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
}

function Draw() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(Draw);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  points.map(p => {
    p.update();
  });
  drawCurves();
}

Draw();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid; background:skyblue}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Меняем координаты узловых точек. Помните, что у `Y` положительное направление вниз.

- определяем углы прямоугольника

`let corners = [[100, 100], [400, 100], [400, 150], [100, 200]];`

```js
// инициировать  canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = (canvas.width = 600),
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = (canvas.height = 400),
  cy = ch / 2;
ctx.fillStyle = "white"

// определить углы прямоугольника
let corners = [[100, 100], [400, 100], [400, 150], [100, 200]];

let amplitud = 20;// амплитуда колебаний
let speed = 0.01;// скорость колебаний
let points = []; // массив точек для рисования кривой

class Point {
  constructor(x, y, hv) {
    // точка колеблется вокруг этой точки (cx, cy)
    this.cx = x;
    this.cy = y;
    // текущий угол колебаний
    this.a = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
    this.hv = hv;// переменная, чтобы знать, является ли колебание горизонтальным или вертикальным

    this.update();
  }

  // функция для обновления значения угла
  update() {
    this.a += speed;

    if (this.hv == 0) {
      this.x = this.cx;
      this.y = this.cy + amplitud * Math.cos(this.a);
    } else {
      this.x = this.cx + amplitud * Math.cos(this.a);
      this.y = this.cy;
    }
  }
}


// функция, чтобы разделить линию, которая идет от a до b в n сегментах
// Я использую полученные точки, чтобы создать новый точечный объект и вставить эту новую точку в массив точек
function divide(n, a, b) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    let p = {
      x: (b[0] - a[0]) * i / n + a[0],
      y: (b[1] - a[1]) * i / n + a[1],
      hv: b[1] - a[1]
    };
    points.push(new Point(p.x, p.y, p.hv));
  }
}

divide(10, corners[0], corners[1]);points.pop();
divide(5, corners[1], corners[2]);points.pop();
divide(10, corners[2], corners[3]);points.pop();
divide(5, corners[3], corners[0]);points.pop();

// это функция, которая берет массив точек и рисует изогнутую линию через эти точки
function drawCurves() {
  //найти первую середину и перейти к ней
  let p = {};
  p.x = (points[points.length - 1].x + points[0].x) / 2;
  p.y = (points[points.length - 1].y + points[0].y) / 2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
  //кривой через остальное, останавливаясь в каждой средней точке
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
    let mp = {};
    mp.x = (points[i].x + points[i + 1].x) / 2;
    mp.y = (points[i].y + points[i + 1].y) / 2;
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(points[i].x, points[i].y, mp.x, mp.y);
  }
  //кривая через последнюю точку, обратно к первой средней точке
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
    points[points.length - 1].x,
    points[points.length - 1].y,
    p.x,
    p.y
  );
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
}

function Draw() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(Draw);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  points.map(p => {
    p.update();
  });
  drawCurves();
}

Draw();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid; background:#6ab150}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

**Увеличиваем скорость колебаний**

`let speed = 0.05;`

```js
// инициировать  canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = (canvas.width = 600),
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = (canvas.height = 400),
  cy = ch / 2;
ctx.fillStyle = "white"

// определить углы прямоугольника
let corners = [[100, 100], [400, 100], [400, 150], [100, 200]];

let amplitud = 20;// амплитуда колебаний
let speed = 0.05;// скорость колебаний
let points = []; // массив точек для рисования кривой

class Point {
  constructor(x, y, hv) {
    // точка колеблется вокруг этой точки (cx, cy)
    this.cx = x;
    this.cy = y;
    // текущий угол колебаний
    this.a = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
    this.hv = hv;// переменная, чтобы знать, является ли колебание горизонтальным или вертикальным

    this.update();
  }

  // функция для обновления значения угла
  update() {
    this.a += speed;

    if (this.hv == 0) {
      this.x = this.cx;
      this.y = this.cy + amplitud * Math.cos(this.a);
    } else {
      this.x = this.cx + amplitud * Math.cos(this.a);
      this.y = this.cy;
    }
  }
}


// функция, чтобы разделить линию, которая идет от a до b в n сегментах
// Я использую полученные точки, чтобы создать новый точечный объект и вставить эту новую точку в массив точек
function divide(n, a, b) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    let p = {
      x: (b[0] - a[0]) * i / n + a[0],
      y: (b[1] - a[1]) * i / n + a[1],
      hv: b[1] - a[1]
    };
    points.push(new Point(p.x, p.y, p.hv));
  }
}

divide(10, corners[0], corners[1]);points.pop();
divide(5, corners[1], corners[2]);points.pop();
divide(10, corners[2], corners[3]);points.pop();
divide(5, corners[3], corners[0]);points.pop();

// это функция, которая берет массив точек и рисует изогнутую линию через эти точки
function drawCurves() {
  //найти первую середину и перейти к ней
  let p = {};
  p.x = (points[points.length - 1].x + points[0].x) / 2;
  p.y = (points[points.length - 1].y + points[0].y) / 2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
  //кривой через остальное, останавливаясь в каждой средней точке
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
    let mp = {};
    mp.x = (points[i].x + points[i + 1].x) / 2;
    mp.y = (points[i].y + points[i + 1].y) / 2;
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(points[i].x, points[i].y, mp.x, mp.y);
  }
  //кривая через последнюю точку, обратно к первой средней точке
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
    points[points.length - 1].x,
    points[points.length - 1].y,
    p.x,
    p.y
  );
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
}

function Draw() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(Draw);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  points.map(p => {
    p.update();
  });
  drawCurves();
}

Draw();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid; background:#6ab150}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

- Амплитуду колебаний

`let amplitud = 50;`

```js
// инициировать  canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = (canvas.width = 600),
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = (canvas.height = 400),
  cy = ch / 2;
ctx.fillStyle = "white"

// определить углы прямоугольника
let corners = [[100, 100], [400, 100], [400, 150], [100, 200]];

let amplitud = 50;// амплитуда колебаний
let speed = 0.05;// скорость колебаний
let points = []; // массив точек для рисования кривой

class Point {
  constructor(x, y, hv) {
    // точка колеблется вокруг этой точки (cx, cy)
    this.cx = x;
    this.cy = y;
    // текущий угол колебаний
    this.a = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
    this.hv = hv;// переменная, чтобы знать, является ли колебание горизонтальным или вертикальным

    this.update();
  }

  // функция для обновления значения угла
  update() {
    this.a += speed;

    if (this.hv == 0) {
      this.x = this.cx;
      this.y = this.cy + amplitud * Math.cos(this.a);
    } else {
      this.x = this.cx + amplitud * Math.cos(this.a);
      this.y = this.cy;
    }
  }
}


// функция, чтобы разделить линию, которая идет от a до b в n сегментах
// Я использую полученные точки, чтобы создать новый точечный объект и вставить эту новую точку в массив точек
function divide(n, a, b) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    let p = {
      x: (b[0] - a[0]) * i / n + a[0],
      y: (b[1] - a[1]) * i / n + a[1],
      hv: b[1] - a[1]
    };
    points.push(new Point(p.x, p.y, p.hv));
  }
}

divide(10, corners[0], corners[1]);points.pop();
divide(5, corners[1], corners[2]);points.pop();
divide(10, corners[2], corners[3]);points.pop();
divide(5, corners[3], corners[0]);points.pop();

// это функция, которая берет массив точек и рисует изогнутую линию через эти точки
function drawCurves() {
  //найти первую середину и перейти к ней
  let p = {};
  p.x = (points[points.length - 1].x + points[0].x) / 2;
  p.y = (points[points.length - 1].y + points[0].y) / 2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
  //кривой через остальное, останавливаясь в каждой средней точке
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
    let mp = {};
    mp.x = (points[i].x + points[i + 1].x) / 2;
    mp.y = (points[i].y + points[i + 1].y) / 2;
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(points[i].x, points[i].y, mp.x, mp.y);
  }
  //кривая через последнюю точку, обратно к первой средней точке
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
    points[points.length - 1].x,
    points[points.length - 1].y,
    p.x,
    p.y
  );
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
}

function Draw() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(Draw);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  points.map(p => {
    p.update();
  });
  drawCurves();
}

Draw();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid; background:#6ab150}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

[Источник скрипта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/932068/28748)

Answer (score 10):

у Вас в codepen.io уже есть готовый код svg

Каким образом это работает ?

Я приведу пример из бесплатного векторного редактора Inkscape

Весь фокус там в анимации path -т.е замкнутой области

Для этого нарисуем обычный circle(смотрим скрины)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

дальше оконтурим объект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выбираем редактировать узлы контуров и рычагов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и меняем нашу фигуру как угодно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не забываем о Редакторе XML который расположен в Пункте Правка и от туда берём наш path и сохраняем это в value="" но помним что любой path начинается с m и заканчивается на z, через точку с запятой вот так :

```html
values="m 171.60117,149.2113 c 0,41.12384 -28.18164,25.3244 -63.87797,25.32441 -35.696332,0 -64.334444,15.78589 -65.389879,-25.32441 -0.914858,-35.63468 24.326526,-46.79487 64.633929,-74.4613 29.43057,-20.200726 64.63392,33.33746 64.63392,74.4613 z; m
171.60117,149.2113 c 0,41.12384 -53.18832,-8.73377 -63.87797,25.32441 C 82.42654,255.13317 43.388756,190.3216 42.333321,149.2113 41.418463,113.57662 66.659847,102.41643 106.96725,74.75 c 29.43057,-20.200726 64.63392,33.33746 64.63392,74.4613 z; m 171.60117,149.2113
c 0,41.12384 -53.18832,-8.73377 -63.87797,25.32441 C 82.42654,255.13317 52.091032,189.16074 42.333321,149.2113 30.245529,99.72218 -12.711983,3.9953599 106.96725,74.75 c 30.72797,18.166446 64.63392,33.33746 64.63392,74.4613 z; m 171.60117,149.2113 c -0.0101,41.12384
-32.55393,42.4426 -63.87797,25.32441 C 40.200847,137.63559 51.571238,187.71436 42.333321,149.2113 30.447804,99.673212 -25.669232,116.42615 106.96725,74.75 c 135.40433,-42.545846 64.644,33.33161 64.63392,74.4613 z; m 171.60117,149.2113 c -0.0101,41.12384
-32.55393,42.4426 -63.87797,25.32441 C 40.200847,137.63559 51.571238,187.71436 42.333321,149.2113 30.447804,99.673212 163.75162,-22.482479 106.96725,74.75 c -71.576575,122.56132 64.644,33.33161 64.63392,74.4613 z; m 171.60117,149.2113 c -7.44959,40.44347
-35.89119,3.1666 -63.87797,25.32441 C 13.926348,248.79693 51.552055,187.79551 42.333321,149.2113 30.494747,99.661972 -5.6305653,75.343332 106.96725,74.75 c 74.96041,-0.395002 73.59304,25.82265 64.63392,74.4613 z
```

Дальше по шагам 
1)

Заголовок и прочее берём с редактора

Пишем smill svg в итоге получаем анимацию:

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  
      viewBox="0 0 560.8 522.6">
  <path fill="#000">
    <animate 
      attributeName="d" 
      dur="2000ms" 
      repeatCount="indefinite"                
      values="m 171.60117,149.2113 c 0,41.12384 -28.18164,25.3244 -63.87797,25.32441 -35.696332,0 -64.334444,15.78589 -65.389879,-25.32441 -0.914858,-35.63468 24.326526,-46.79487 64.633929,-74.4613 29.43057,-20.200726 64.63392,33.33746 64.63392,74.4613 z;
              
  m 171.60117,149.2113 c 0,41.12384 -53.18832,-8.73377 -63.87797,25.32441 C 82.42654,255.13317 43.388756,190.3216 42.333321,149.2113 41.418463,113.57662 66.659847,102.41643 106.96725,74.75 c 29.43057,-20.200726 64.63392,33.33746 64.63392,74.4613 z;
 m 171.60117,149.2113 c 0,41.12384 -53.18832,-8.73377 -63.87797,25.32441 C 82.42654,255.13317 52.091032,189.16074 42.333321,149.2113 30.245529,99.72218 -12.711983,3.9953599 106.96725,74.75 c 30.72797,18.166446 64.63392,33.33746 64.63392,74.4613 z;
              
 m 171.60117,149.2113 c -0.0101,41.12384 -32.55393,42.4426 -63.87797,25.32441 C 40.200847,137.63559 51.571238,187.71436 42.333321,149.2113 30.447804,99.673212 -25.669232,116.42615 106.96725,74.75 c 135.40433,-42.545846 64.644,33.33161 64.63392,74.4613 z;
              
  m 171.60117,149.2113 c -0.0101,41.12384 -32.55393,42.4426 -63.87797,25.32441 C 40.200847,137.63559 51.571238,187.71436 42.333321,149.2113 30.447804,99.673212 163.75162,-22.482479 106.96725,74.75 c -71.576575,122.56132 64.644,33.33161 64.63392,74.4613 z;
   m 171.60117,149.2113 c -7.44959,40.44347 -35.89119,3.1666 -63.87797,25.32441 C 13.926348,248.79693 51.552055,187.79551 42.333321,149.2113 30.494747,99.661972 -5.6305653,75.343332 106.96725,74.75 c 74.96041,-0.395002 73.59304,25.82265 64.63392,74.4613 z
              "></animate>
  </path>
</svg>
```

Сама фишка в том что количество path в animate не имеет значение
Что бы анимация была плавная надо увеличить время и после самого последнего пути добавить самый первый путь вот так : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/mvwwZG

Answer (score 6):

Есть такая замечательная библиотека [flubber](https://github.com/veltman/flubber).

Она как раз решает проблему интерполяции между различными `svg path`, легка в использовании в паре с `d3.js` необходимо лишь задать начальное и конечное значение пути.

```js
var pathStrings = [...document.querySelectorAll("path")].map(d => d.getAttribute("d"));
d3.selectAll("path").filter((d, i) => i).remove();
d3.select("path").style("display", "block").call(animate);

function animate(sel) {
  var start = pathStrings.shift();
  var end = pathStrings[0];
  pathStrings.push(start);
  sel.datum({start, end}).transition().duration(1500)
    .attrTween("d", d => flubber.interpolate(d.start, d.end, {maxSegmentLength: 0.1}))
    .on("end", e => sel.call(animate));
}
```

```css
path {
  fill: #aa00ff;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flubber@0.3.0"></script>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="150">
  <g transform="scale(5 5)">
    <path d="M12 17.27L18.18 21l-1.64-7.03L22 9.24l-7.19-.61L12 2 9.19 8.63 2 9.24l5.46 4.73L5.82 21z"/>
    <path d="M12 21.35l-1.45-1.32C5.4 15.36 2 12.28 2 8.5 2 5.42 4.42 3 7.5 3c1.74 0 3.41.81 4.5 2.09C13.09 3.81 14.76 3 16.5 3 19.58 3 22 5.42 22 8.5c0 3.78-3.4 6.86-8.55 11.54L12 21.35z"/>
    
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: хороший плагин, впрочем их много в сети. Но у  всех есть свой изьян - если у двух путей не будут совпадать количество узлов в двух путях, либо команды `С`, `Q` `T` кривых Безье не будут одинаковыми в одинаковых по счёту узлах, либо пути будут иметь разрывы, либо контуры будут не одинарными Эти библиотеки работать не будут. Вы проверяли этот плагин на эти нюансы? Тем не менее от меня плюс.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT по этому признаку и отобрана, пока сбоев не было

Comment: а где ты берешь второй путь. Если есть только один, который надо изменить.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT у меня есть свои наработки, например редактор контрольных точек, мини редактор короче

Comment: @Alexandr_TT https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/full/qLLqya

Comment: нормально, интересно. Жаль, что нет кривых Безье и вывода готового кода. Или есть?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT вообще это редактор, часть проекта побольше, я там домики поверх карты рисую. У либы есть метод getImage, возвращает svg, редактор кривых тоже есть - кнопочка Edit, но пока там только один тип сегментов пути доступен, кроме m и l