# Анимация svg глаз кролика с помощью атрибутов path "d" и "keyTimes"

Tags: css, html5, svg, анимация, svg-animation

Как можно анимировать svg картинку? Хочу чтобы кролик моргал глазами.

```css
#pa8{
width: 250px;
height:250px;
}
```

```html
 <img  id="pa8" src="https://vk.com/doc531961572_499477369?hash=a859da87b9143a35ba&dl=e70423d886a08a2415.svg">
```

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну во первых заголовок был изменен, когда уже были два ответа именно с такой реализацией, как в заголовке вопроса. Во вторых, когда проходит время, почти невозможно найти конкретный пост в этом море безликих вопросов, типа - "у меня проблема с анимацией", "мне нужно сделать анимацию , как на том ресурсе"  Вот только с этой целью я изменяю заголовки на конкретные формулировки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Взял код из предыдущего ответа, добавил кролику зрачок глаза. переработал анимацию с учетом добавления атрибута `keyTimes`, которым задаётся неравномерность движения века глаза.

Основное условие применения этого атрибута -
**Количество значений keytimes и values в `path` должно совпадать.**

`keyTimes="0;0.15;0.18;0.85;1"`  имеет `5` значений, ровно столько значений должно быть в формуле анимации атрибута `d` path - `5` подробнее [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1674)

```css
.container {
width:90%;
height:90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
viewBox="0 0 1460 1880"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"> 
  <!-- Тело кролика -->
 <g transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M7465 12781 c-206 -74 -565 -358 -1135 -897 -433 -408 -844 -865
-1110 -1231 -40 -57 -75 -101 -77 -99 -2 2 -23 68 -48 147 -100 326 -245 709
-348 914 -180 362 -327 487 -577 487 -183 1 -334 -74 -510 -251 -384 -387
-558 -881 -660 -1871 -63 -615 -123 -1818 -119 -2382 0 -92 -3 -172 -7 -179
-12 -19 -221 -114 -334 -152 -58 -19 -195 -56 -305 -82 -329 -77 -413 -108
-565 -210 -120 -80 -214 -167 -336 -308 -183 -212 -290 -389 -353 -582 -33
-102 -64 -255 -117 -565 -77 -458 -145 -682 -301 -994 -80 -159 -157 -284
-309 -502 -165 -236 -209 -310 -236 -398 -41 -133 -13 -219 127 -394 84 -106
147 -202 177 -270 11 -26 53 -144 93 -262 40 -119 87 -246 103 -282 88 -194
244 -348 421 -417 65 -26 69 -26 311 -23 190 2 267 -1 345 -14 96 -16 152 -16
301 2 l51 6 12 -48 c19 -73 52 -153 182 -435 227 -494 333 -686 500 -910 139
-184 471 -569 492 -569 11 0 13 -4 -132 205 -243 350 -403 607 -521 840 -154
301 -217 508 -276 906 l-5 35 133 12 c330 28 668 114 873 221 38 20 137 83
220 141 194 135 316 197 501 255 366 114 501 168 686 271 382 214 748 538 958
850 151 223 271 582 270 807 -1 78 -6 69 -65 -108 -55 -166 -169 -403 -255
-532 -189 -282 -468 -517 -828 -697 -273 -137 -518 -213 -948 -296 -685 -132
-778 -168 -1122 -429 -190 -144 -293 -195 -472 -234 -85 -19 -119 -21 -320
-17 -397 8 -505 5 -636 -19 -229 -40 -282 -27 -360 90 -53 80 -264 509 -292
593 -25 75 -20 90 27 82 93 -15 206 -99 406 -302 152 -155 202 -195 217 -171
13 21 9 72 -17 191 -32 148 -32 215 -1 281 33 69 74 114 265 288 198 181 471
462 494 509 14 28 14 33 2 36 -38 9 -169 -86 -509 -365 -347 -286 -465 -361
-580 -370 -235 -19 -511 197 -582 455 -15 54 -16 74 -7 127 12 68 9 63 588
1210 274 544 309 619 380 827 52 150 73 246 115 515 46 299 84 398 201 514
120 119 261 167 624 214 290 38 418 71 530 135 28 16 111 77 185 134 216 169
371 253 673 365 76 28 208 72 294 96 365 105 533 111 701 26 74 -37 146 -94
312 -245 253 -230 344 -293 434 -303 35 -4 47 -1 74 22 87 73 107 184 122 685
18 586 38 846 85 1129 134 789 419 1501 880 2196 120 181 327 464 390 533 106
118 99 19 -56 -833 -251 -1382 -415 -1953 -857 -2996 -86 -204 -125 -318 -153
-452 -19 -91 -22 -131 -20 -377 1 -363 16 -670 36 -743 59 -226 219 -308 770
-397 318 -52 671 -68 885 -41 224 28 477 89 820 198 96 31 197 62 223 70 76
23 47 26 -39 4 -196 -50 -614 -118 -939 -153 -186 -20 -646 -17 -765 5 -120
22 -272 74 -347 118 -96 57 -185 155 -238 262 -68 138 -88 225 -89 387 -1 199
37 323 165 546 214 373 535 1236 748 2015 128 469 230 993 361 1859 109 723
144 892 251 1213 59 177 72 273 44 331 -31 65 -89 80 -180 47z m-3270 -876
c46 -27 71 -58 112 -141 78 -155 138 -391 294 -1164 44 -217 96 -456 116 -530
49 -188 49 -175 8 -270 -52 -122 -121 -326 -156 -462 -56 -223 -81 -421 -99
-773 -27 -531 -72 -602 -429 -686 -457 -107 -516 -127 -829 -286 -112 -57
-206 -103 -209 -103 -3 0 -2 15 2 33 3 17 10 478 15 1022 8 955 12 1090 45
1420 42 408 115 782 205 1040 46 133 158 356 238 475 243 364 509 528 687 425z"/>
</g>
     <!-- контур глаза -->
   <g  transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
   <path id="contur" fill="#C6CDEA" stroke="#d3d3d3" id="eye" d="M4379.5 6012.1C3644.6 6282.7 2221.8 5595.1 3760 5379c148-19 288 19 417 114 109 81 171 182 246 403-109.3 355.6-20.6-339.3-43.5 116.1z" stroke-width="30"/>
   </g> 
      <!-- Зрачок глаза -->
     <g id="eye">
   <ellipse cx="392.3" cy="707.6" rx="25.9" ry="28.5" style="fill:#0c0813;stroke-width:3;stroke:#0c0813"/>
   <ellipse cx="66.7" cy="800.8" rx="12.6" ry="5.6" transform="matrix(0.93017514,-0.36711607,0.39971713,0.91663854,0,0)" style="fill-opacity:0.9;fill:#dddceb"/> 
    </g>   
  <!-- Анимация века глаза -->
      <g  transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
 <path id="veko" fill="#d3d3d3" id="eye" d="M4379.5 6012.1C3644.6 6282.7 2221.8 5595.1 3760 5379c148-19 288 19 417 114 109 81 171 182 246 403-109.3 355.6-20.6-339.3-43.5 116.1z" stroke-width="30">
   <animate 
     attributeName="d"
  dur="3s"
  values="M4379.5 6012.1C3644.6 6282.7 2221.8 5595.1 3760 5379c148-19 288 19 417 114 109 81 171 182 246 403-109.3 355.6-20.6-339.3-43.5 116.1z;
  M 4379.5402,6012.1314 C 4540.5157,5168.8032 2367.525,5413.8361 3760,5379 c 148,-19 288,19 417,114 109,81 171,182 246,403 -109.3454,355.5504 -20.6455,-339.2546 -43.4598,116.1314 z;
  M4379.5 6012.1C3644.6 6282.7 2221.8 5595.1 3760 5379c148-19 288 19 417 114 109 81 171 182 246 403-109.3 355.6-20.6-339.3-43.5 116.1z;
   M 4379.5402,6012.1314 C 4540.5157,5168.8032 2367.525,5413.8361 3760,5379 c 148,-19 288,19 417,114 109,81 171,182 246,403 -109.3454,355.5504 -20.6455,-339.2546 -43.4598,116.1314 z;
   M4379.5 6012.1C3644.6 6282.7 2221.8 5595.1 3760 5379c148-19 288 19 417 114 109 81 171 182 246 403-109.3 355.6-20.6-339.3-43.5 116.1z;"
  keyTimes="0;0.15;0.18;0.85;1" 
  repeatCount="indefinite"
  />
  </path> 
  </g>
  
  </svg>
  </div>
```

Comment: Саша блеск ....а как понять какой косяк в keytimes ?

Comment: И кстати я Пашу выгнал с офиса ...слижком уж нахальный ...

Comment: @MaximLensky то то я гляжу его активность упала. А насчет keyTimes надо оч. внимательно повторить правильный синтаксис. Вот например,- у меня была лишняя точка с запятой в `keyTimes` и в Chrome не работало. Лишний пробел, тоже может быть причиной, не срабатывания в одном из браузеров.

Comment: да ладно ...попросит у коллектива прощения приму назад ..но всё интересно  мне про keytimes на MDN сказано что количество точек должно ровняться values, как у тебя получилось без этого правила ?

Comment: прошу прощения я в Садик за сыном ходил ...

Comment: @MaximLensky я не доверяю MDN, очень плохо SVG излагают, и вводят в заблуждение. Вот сделай вместо 5 точек, `4` и не будет работать У меня и сделано -5 значений `values` и 5 значений `keyTimes`/

Comment: я вообще не доверяю официальным источникам ...ладно спасибо ..я понял буду бороться ...удачи Саша ..всего хорошего

Comment: Саша ты здесь ещё ?

Answer (score 4):

**Если потребуется объяснения каким образом это сделано подробно я объясню**

Как было сказано на Toster что анимировать img не возможно и это обсуждалось уже милион раз здесь , в вашем случае надо взять весь код из img открыть обычным халявным notepad++ 
и вынести SVG в html и анемировать тот путь

> Вот реализация вашей задумки :
>   https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/PgLdog

я искал в ручную этот path и так как он был ниже того глаза то я просто переместил path c анимацией в самый низ ...

И что хочу сказать что toster stackoverflow не база бесплатных исполнений ХОТЕЛОК

Конкретно вот этот участок отвечает за эффект :

```html
<path fill="rgb(204, 203, 209)" stroke="rgba(204, 203, 209, 0.8)"  stroke-width="1px" d="">
     
     <animate 
          attributeName="d"
          dur="0.6s" 
          repeatCount="indefinite"
         values="m 401.6,414.3 c 4.9,-1.8 10.2,0.2 14.5,2.6 1.1,7.7 2.8,15.3 3.3,23.1 11.1,-1.4 21.6,-6.2 32.9,-5.6 6.7,0.3 13.4,0.4 20,1.7 8.4,1.8 17.1,2.3 25.6,3.3 10.8,1.5 21.5,4.1 31.4,8.6 5,2.2 9.5,5.3 14.4,7.6 13.5,6.1 25,17 31.7,30.3 0.9,2.4 3.8,1.6 5.9,1.8 12.5,-0.3 25.1,1.1 37,4.9 -2.8,6.6 -5,13.4 -7.4,20.1 -9.8,3.6 -17.7,10.5 -25.8,16.9 -20.8,15.6 -40.4,33.2 -55.5,54.5 -3,-2 -6.3,-3.5 -9.7,-4.6 2.3,-3.3 5.3,-6.1 7.8,-9.3 10.3,-15 13.7,-34.3 10.3,-52 -1,-5.4 -1.9,-11.1 -5.2,-15.6 -5.1,-17.9 -15.9,-34.1 -30.3,-45.8 -13.6,-10.9 -31.9,-17.1 -49.3,-13.2 -13.3,2.9 -24.3,12.6 -30.9,24.2 -6.6,11.5 -6.4,58.4 -1.80496,71.90143 17.89614,29.43059 22.89486,41.95738 12.20496,54.79857 -53.1943,77.3721 -134.27379,-35.61602 -102.8,-68.1 -3.5,11.3 -3.8,23.4 -2,35 2.5,11.9 7.8,23.1 14.8,33 0,2.7 1.7,4.8 3.4,6.7 7.6,9.7 17.9,17.3 29.5,21.4 7.4,2.9 15.5,2.7 23.3,3.1 -4.8,6.3 -6.3,14.1 -7.9,21.7 -25.1,-5 -51.1,-4.9 -76.4,-1 -7.3,1.4 -14.9,2 -21.9,4.8 -9,-2.9 -17.9,-5.7 -27.1,-7.8 4.5,-16.1 3.3,-33 5.7,-49.4 1,-10.9 4.6,-21.3 7.2,-31.9 3.9,-10.5 7.8,-21.3 14.8,-30.3 9.3,-12 21.2,-21.8 33.2,-30.9 0.8,1.8 1.5,3.7 2.2,5.7 8.2,-8.2 15.6,-17.9 26.3,-23 7.5,-3.4 15.1,-7.2 20.9,-13.1 2.2,-2.2 2.5,-5.5 3,-8.4 -4.9,2.6 -9.5,6 -14,9.2 -3.5,-3.4 -7.2,-6.6 -10.7,-10 -6.8,4.2 -12.9,9.6 -17.5,16.2 -2.3,-3.2 -5.8,-7 -4.4,-11.3 2.4,-5.5 8.5,-7.9 13.9,-9.3 9.8,-1.8 19.8,-0.9 29.6,-2.9 -10.4,-7.3 -23.6,-4.1 -35.4,-4.3 -1.8,-4.1 -5.3,-8.8 -3.1,-13.5 3.3,-7.8 11.9,-12.1 20.1,-11.9 11.5,-0.1 22.5,4.6 31.8,11 4.5,3.1 7.7,7.7 12.4,10.6 2.3,1.5 5.3,0.8 7.9,0.7 -4.3,-5.5 -10.8,-9.2 -14,-15.6 -3.3,-5.9 -0.4,-14.5 6.1,-16.6 z;
M401.6,414c4.9-1.8,10.2,0.2,14.5,2.6c1.1,7.7,2.8,15.3,3.3,23.1c11.1-1.4,21.6-6.2,32.9-5.6
  c6.7,0.3,13.4,0.4,20,1.7c8.4,1.8,17.1,2.3,25.6,3.3c10.8,1.5,21.5,4.1,31.4,8.6c5,2.2,9.5,5.3,14.4,7.6c13.5,6.1,25,17,31.7,30.3
  c0.9,2.4,3.8,1.6,5.9,1.8c12.5-0.3,25.1,1.1,37,4.9c-2.8,6.6-5,13.4-7.4,20.1c-9.8,3.6-17.7,10.5-25.8,16.9
  c-20.8,15.6-40.4,33.2-55.5,54.5c-3-2-6.3-3.5-9.7-4.6c2.3-3.3,5.3-6.1,7.8-9.3c10.3-15,13.7-34.3,10.3-52
  c-1-5.4-1.9-11.1-5.2-15.6c-5.1-17.9-15.9-34.1-30.3-45.8c-13.6-10.9-31.9-17.1-49.3-13.2c-13.3,2.9-24.3,12.6-30.9,24.2
  c-6.6,11.5-9.1,25-8.9,38.2c-13.2-11.3-31.5-18.3-48.9-13.9c-16.7,4.1-29.5,18.2-34.6,34.3c-3.5,11.3-3.8,23.4-2,35
  c2.5,11.9,7.8,23.1,14.8,33c0,2.7,1.7,4.8,3.4,6.7c7.6,9.7,17.9,17.3,29.5,21.4c7.4,2.9,15.5,2.7,23.3,3.1
  c-4.8,6.3-6.3,14.1-7.9,21.7c-25.1-5-51.1-4.9-76.4-1c-7.3,1.4-14.9,2-21.9,4.8c-9-2.9-17.9-5.7-27.1-7.8c4.5-16.1,3.3-33,5.7-49.4
  c1-10.9,4.6-21.3,7.2-31.9c3.9-10.5,7.8-21.3,14.8-30.3c9.3-12,21.2-21.8,33.2-30.9c0.8,1.8,1.5,3.7,2.2,5.7
  c8.2-8.2,15.6-17.9,26.3-23c7.5-3.4,15.1-7.2,20.9-13.1c2.2-2.2,2.5-5.5,3-8.4c-4.9,2.6-9.5,6-14,9.2c-3.5-3.4-7.2-6.6-10.7-10
  c-6.8,4.2-12.9,9.6-17.5,16.2c-2.3-3.2-5.8-7-4.4-11.3c2.4-5.5,8.5-7.9,13.9-9.3c9.8-1.8,19.8-0.9,29.6-2.9
  c-10.4-7.3-23.6-4.1-35.4-4.3c-1.8-4.1-5.3-8.8-3.1-13.5c3.3-7.8,11.9-12.1,20.1-11.9c11.5-0.1,22.5,4.6,31.8,11
  c4.5,3.1,7.7,7.7,12.4,10.6c2.3,1.5,5.3,0.8,7.9,0.7c-4.3-5.5-10.8-9.2-14-15.6C392.2,424.7,395.1,416.1,401.6,414z"
              fill="freeze"
      />
    
  </path>
```

Прошу модераторов простить меня за то что выложил код в песочнице но максимальная длина сообщения 30000 а код составил 35 000

Comment: в Edge не работает но работает с планшета

Comment: а можете пожалуйста второй глаз тоже анимировать?

Comment: @Ivan912 это не фриланс, вам показали два разработчика как делать это, покажите ваши попытки ..

Comment: ну тогда можете обьяснить как вы это сделали?

Comment: @Ivan912 это можно ...тем вивер есть ?

Comment: написал на эмейл

Answer (score 4):

Пришлось подрихтовать зайца, чтобы он лез в сниппет, я уменьшил точность точек в путях при помощи [svg-optimiser](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-optimiser) и убрал у него несколько областей.

Далее открываем отладчик `Сhrome` и при помощи инспектора [image: i] выясняем как найти тот путь, который формирует глаза:

[image: e]

Как оказалось это второй по счету элемент с классом `.a`

После манипуляций c путем выясняем какие части атрибута пути `d` формируют внутренние отверстия для левого и правого глаза черном полигоне

Разделить путь на внешний контур и внутренние отверстия легко вызвав `.split('z')` на строке атрибута `d`

Далее добавляем 2 круга, которые будем двигать по кликам мышки и используем 2 пути найденных на предыдущем шаге в качестве `clip-path` для них

[image: a]

```js
let d=document
let e=d.querySelectorAll('.a')[1].getAttribute('d').split('z')
d.querySelector('svg').innerHTML+=`<defs>
<clipPath id="r"><path d="${e[1]}"/></clipPath>
<clipPath id="l"><path d="${e[2]}"/></clipPath></defs>
<g stroke="#000" stroke-width="10">
<circle id="right" class="b" r="80" clip-path="url(#r)"/>
<circle id="left" class="b" r="70" clip-path="url(#l)"/>
</g>`
let t,dir=-1,vr=0,vl=0
let xy=(e,x,y) => e.setAttribute('cx', x)||e.setAttribute('cy', y)
let tr=(e,x,y) => e.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${x},${y})`)
let l=(type,i) => addEventListener(type,()=>dir=i)
e=d.querySelectorAll('.a')
t=new Date().getTime()
l('mousedown',1)
l('mouseup',-1)
setInterval(()=>{
 dir=1
 setTimeout(()=>dir=-1,300)
},3000)
anim()
addEventListener('mousemove',ev=>{
 let x=ev.clientX/innerWidth-0.5
 let y=ev.clientY/innerHeight-0.5
 tr(e[2],x*50,y*50)
 tr(e[3],x*40-10,y*30)
})
function anim() {
 let dt=new Date().getTime()-t
 vr=Math.min(1,Math.max(vr+dt/88*dir,0))
 vl=Math.min(1,Math.max(vl+dt/200*dir,0))
 xy(d.querySelector('#left'),345+vl*50,420+vl*125)
 xy(d.querySelector('#right'),400+vr*50,370+vr*150)
 t=new Date().getTime()
 requestAnimationFrame(anim)
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 681.6 1184" style="height:98vh;position:fixed;right:0"><style>.b{fill:#CCCBD1}.i{fill:#E9ECF2}</style><path d="M639.1 534.3c5.5-0.4 8.8-5.1 12.6-8.4 7.9 9.4 18.2 16.5 28.7 22.8 0.4 0.2 0.8 0.5 1.1 0.7 0-0.1 0-0.3 0-0.4 -0.1-2.4-0.4-4.7-1.1-7 -0.3-0.9-0.3-1.6-0.1-2.3 -6-3.1-11.4-7.1-16.1-12 -5.3-5.9-9-14.2-7-22.2 0.3-0.8 0.6-1.7 0.9-2.5 -0.2-0.7-0.2-1.5 0.1-2.3 0.4-1.4 0.9-2.7 1.4-4.1 -0.9-3-1.6-6.1-2-9.2 -1.7-1.9-2.6-4.6-2.3-7 -1.1 0-2.3-0.5-3.1-1.2 -0.7 0.3-1.4 0.5-2.1 0.5 -0.3 0-0.6 0-1-0.1 -0.3 0.1-0.7 0.1-1 0.1 -0.4 0-0.7 0-1.1-0.1 0 0 0 0.1 0 0.1 -5.1-1.2-10.1-2.7-15.2-4 4.9-8.8 10.6-17.2 17.2-24.8 -0.7-1.6-1.4-3.1-2-4.7 -7.8 8.7-14.9 18-20.5 28.3 -8.1-1.8-16.2-3.6-24.4-5 -3.4-0.6-6.7-2-9.4-4.1 -15-11.3-30.8-21.7-47.3-30.7 -18.1-10.6-39.7-13-60.3-12.8 9.7-17.6 20.9-34.7 26.3-54.2 4.2-15.1 8.6-30.3 10.3-46 1.6-12.5 0.2-25.2 1.2-37.8 0.9-16.6-2.6-33-5.5-49.2 -2.4-9.3-2.2-19-4.8-28.3 -5.1-23.3-14.1-45.5-19.7-68.7 -2.6-8.2-6.5-16-9.6-24 -4.7-11.4-9.2-22.9-15.3-33.6 -3.3-6.3-8.1-12-9.2-19.2 0.1-8.5 4.3-16.4 3.8-25 -0.2-3.8-0.8-8.1-3.8-10.8 -3.6-2.9-8.6-3-12.8-1.6 -7.3 2.3-12.9 7.7-18.7 12.5 -8 6.6-16 13.3-23.3 20.7 -7.3 7.3-11.6 16.9-18.1 24.8 -17.6 21.8-29.2 47.8-37.6 74.3 -11.3 31.8-10.8 66.4-6.3 99.4 1.4 12.6 3.3 25.2 6.4 37.5 2.2 11.5 3.6 23.4 8.9 33.9 4.7 9.7 8.2 19.9 12.3 29.9 4 10.4 9.8 20.1 14.8 30.1 3.6 7.4 8.4 14.2 12.5 21.3 -5.5 3.4-7.9 9.6-10.3 15.2 -11.6-5.3-24.7-7.1-37.3-5.1 -4.1-13.4-8.7-26.6-14-39.5 -5-11.3-11-22.1-15.4-33.6 -2.4-6.7-6.1-12.9-10.2-18.7 -10.3-14-19.7-28.8-31.2-41.9 -20.2-25.1-43.6-48.6-72.7-63.2 -20.6-10.2-42-19.1-64.6-24 -8.9-2.1-18-2.9-27.1-3.9 -9-0.9-17.8-3.7-26.9-3.6 -12.1 0.1-24.1 1.8-36.1 3.2 -7.2 0.9-14.7 1.9-20.9 5.9 -4 2.7-7.2 7.7-5.6 12.7 2.6 6.2 8.2 10.5 13.9 13.9 4.9 3 10.6 5.3 13.9 10.3 2.6 5.1 4 10.7 5.7 16.1 2.2 8.1 5.5 15.7 8.8 23.4 5.2 12 10.6 24 16.3 35.8 3.4 6.2 7.2 12.2 10.7 18.4 11 18.8 20.6 38.5 34.2 55.5 12.1 14.6 21.8 31.2 35.1 44.8 3.7 4 8 7.5 12.2 11.1 8.4 7.3 15.9 15.5 24.9 22.1 12.9 9.6 27.1 17.1 41.3 24.5 19.9 10.5 42.3 14.8 64.1 19.5 -9.8 11.8-23.9 20.7-29.1 35.8 -2.9 8.7-6.5 17.1-8.4 26 -2.5 10.9-4.6 21.8-5.7 32.9 -0.1 9-1.2 17.9-2 26.9 -0.5 4.3-1.1 8.6-2.6 12.7 -28.5-5.6-57.4-0.2-85.5 4.9 -2 0.3-2.4 2.6-3.4 4 8-0.9 15.9-2.6 24-3.7 20.7-3.3 41.8-3.8 62.5-0.4 -1.6 10.3-8.6 18.2-14.2 26.5 -20.9 1.8-41.7 6.5-60.9 15 -17 7.5-33.2 16.6-49.6 25.4 -0.2 1.6-0.4 3.3-0.6 5 16.8-8.9 33.5-18.1 51.3-25.1 17.9-7 36.8-11.9 56-13.4 -2.9 6.2-5.8 12.4-7.5 19.1 -26.3 9.6-47.8 28.2-68.9 45.9 -1.8 1.2-1.3 3.6-1.5 5.5 7.2-5.4 14-11.4 21.2-16.8 14.7-11.2 30.3-21.5 47.6-28.2 -0.9 5.9-2 11.9-2.2 17.9 -1.2 13.1 1 26.2 3.8 39 4.7 18.6 13.1 35.9 23.1 52.2 5.4 8.8 12.4 16.3 19 24.2 6.3 7.4 12.6 14.7 19.4 21.6 10.7 11.1 23.3 20.1 35.7 29.1 8.6 6.2 18.6 9.9 28.4 13.7 9.6 4.3 19.7 7.3 30.1 8.7 11.2 1.3 22.2 4.7 33.6 4.3 8.5-0.3 17.1 1 25.6 0.1 9.6-1.1 19.3-1.9 28.9-3.3 -1.6 7.2-3 14.4-4.5 21.5 -38.1 7.6-76.6 12.7-115.1 17.8 -35.2 6.7-71.1 9.9-107 8.9 -3.7-4.3-5.2-10-7.9-14.8 -3.3-6.4-8.9-11.1-14.9-14.8 -7.5-4.4-15.6-7.6-23.7-10.8 -0.9-13.2 6.9-26 3.2-39.1 -4.4-12.4-16.8-20.9-29.5-22.8 -15.1 1.8-28.3 15.2-29.5 30.5 0.1 8 1 16.2 3.9 23.7 4.5 9.5 13.4 15.9 19.5 24.3 -3.3 3-6.5 6.1-9.8 9.3 -27.9-5.6-54.5-17.4-83.1-18.5 -9.9-0.2-20.8-0.1-29.1 6.1 -7 4.9-7.7 15.6-2.9 22.3 5.9 8.6 15.5 13.7 24.9 17.6 20.5 8 43.2 4.9 64.2 10.3 -3.4 3.6-7.9 6-12.6 7.6 -18.5 7.1-34.7 18.6-51.9 28.2 -8.5 4.7-13.3 14-14.9 23.3 -0.4 6.4 3.5 13 9.3 15.9 7.9 4.3 17.3 5.4 26.1 4 17.6-2.7 33.3-12.7 45.6-25.3 5-4.7 8.5-10.8 14.3-14.6 2.9-1.7 7.4-3.3 9.8 0 -10.2 14.5-23.1 28.2-27.3 46 -1.9 5.9 0.4 12 2.2 17.6 2.1 6.1 4.8 12.5 10 16.8 6 4.8 14.8 6.9 21.9 3.2 3.5-2 6.4-4.9 9.5-7.4 7.1-6.2 13.9-14.2 14.9-24 1.1-12.3 1.6-24.7 1.4-37 12.1 1.7 25.8-0.2 34.9-8.9 7.6-6.9 12.2-16.4 16-25.8 14-4 28.6-1.7 42.8-3.4 12.2-1.2 24.1-3.8 36.2-5.6 11.8-2.1 23.8-3.7 35.7-5.5 15.3-3 30.7-5.5 46.1-8.4 21-4.2 42-8.4 62.8-13.6 -1.7 27.2-1.1 54.9 6.4 81.3 7.8 29.5 25.7 56.5 50.8 74.1 33 23.6 74.1 33.1 114.1 34.3 14.5 0.6 28.9-1 43.3-2.4 1.5-2.6 0.9-5.7 0.9-8.6 -13.6 2.1-27.4 3.1-41.2 2.9 -37.1-0.6-75-8.8-106.4-29.2 -24.6-15.8-43-40.5-51.6-68.3 -7.3-22.5-9.3-46.5-8.7-70 0.9-23.5 4.3-46.8 10.1-69.6 14.3-1.2 28.4-4.2 42-8.9 8.6-3.1 16.9-7 25.6-9.9 16.2-6.6 32-14 48.2-20.5 9-4.4 18.1-8.8 27.4-12.7 19.2-9.4 38.2-19.9 54.6-33.7 0.1-3.1-0.1-6.1-0.2-9.2 -14 12.5-30.5 21.8-47.1 30.3 -11.4 5.8-22.3 12.5-34.2 17.2 -25.5 11.3-51.1 22.5-77.4 31.7 -22.1 7.4-45.3 10.7-68.5 12.7 -7.3 0.7-14.6 1.2-21.9 0.7 -16.1-0.8-32.3-1.9-47.8-6.3 -7-2-14.1-3.5-20.9-6.1 -11-3.8-22.3-7.4-31.8-14.3 -6.2-4.5-12.7-8.6-18.4-13.7 -6.4-5.9-13.3-11.2-19.4-17.5 -5.1-5-9.1-10.9-13.9-16.2 -6.2-6.9-12.6-13.6-17.5-21.5 -11-16-20-33.8-23.8-53.1 -1.3-6.8-2.9-13.6-4.3-20.4 -1.9-12.8 0.5-25.8 3.4-38.2 16.3-5.9 33.4-8.7 50.3-12.3 1.7-0.4 3.5-0.9 4.4-2.5 -0.3-2.2-3-1.2-4.4-1.3 -16.5 2.5-33 5.7-49 10.4 2.5-6 5.7-11.8 8.6-17.6 13.4-1.1 26.8-0.8 40.3-0.9 4.2-0.1 9 0.7 12.2-2.6 -3.1-2.7-7.4-2.1-11.2-2.3 -12.2-0.4-24.4-0.6-36.6-0.2 2.9-4 5.7-8.2 7.7-12.7 1.6-3.5 2.7-7.3 4.3-10.8 0.3-1.8 2.1-0.7 3.3-0.6 4.7 1.1 9.4 2.4 14 3.9 9 2.4 17.8 5.6 26.6 8.6 2.4 0.8 5 1.8 7.6 0.9 0.3-1.2 0-2.1-1.2-2.5 -6.8-3.6-14.2-5.4-21.3-8.2 -9-2.9-17.9-5.7-27.1-7.8 4.5-16.1 3.3-33 5.7-49.4 1-10.9 4.6-21.3 7.2-31.9 3.9-10.5 7.8-21.3 14.8-30.3 9.3-12 21.2-21.8 33.2-30.9 0.8 1.8 1.5 3.7 2.2 5.7 8.2-8.2 15.6-17.9 26.3-23 7.5-3.4 15.1-7.2 20.9-13.1 2.2-2.2 2.5-5.5 3-8.4 -4.9 2.6-9.5 6-14 9.2 -3.5-3.4-7.2-6.6-10.7-10 -6.8 4.2-12.9 9.6-17.5 16.2 -2.3-3.2-5.8-7-4.4-11.3 2.4-5.5 8.5-7.9 13.9-9.3 9.8-1.8 19.8-0.9 29.6-2.9 -10.4-7.3-23.6-4.1-35.4-4.3 -1.8-4.1-5.3-8.8-3.1-13.5 3.3-7.8 11.9-12.1 20.1-11.9 11.5-0.1 22.5 4.6 31.8 11 4.5 3.1 7.7 7.7 12.4 10.6 2.3 1.5 5.3 0.8 7.9 0.7 -4.3-5.5-10.8-9.2-14-15.6 -3.2-5.9-0.4-14.5 6.2-16.5 4.9-1.8 10.2 0.2 14.5 2.6 1.1 7.7 2.8 15.3 3.3 23.1 11.1-1.4 21.6-6.2 32.9-5.6 6.7 0.3 13.4 0.4 20 1.7 -0.4-1.2-0.8-2.4-1.1-3.5 18.1-3.1 36.6-1.1 54.2 3.5 15.7 4.2 30.3 11.9 43.5 21.3 8.5 5.7 16.8 11.6 24.5 18.3 2.3 2.4 5.7 2.4 8.8 2.9 7 0.8 13.9 2.1 20.7 3.9 -1.6 3.3-3.2 6.7-4.6 10.1 -2.8 6.6-5 13.4-7.4 20.1 -1.4 4-2.6 8-3.8 12 -1.3 4.2-2.9 8.5-2.3 13.1 1.5-1.2 3.4-2.3 4-4.3 3-8.8 5.6-17.7 8.9-26.4 1.8-5.2 3.7-10.3 6-15.3 1.2-2.7 2.4-5.5 3.7-8.1 7.3 1.5 14.4 3.4 21.5 5.7 0.6 1 1.3 2 1.9 3 0.3 0.5 0.8 1.4 1.1 1.8 -5.5 7.4-11.3 14.4-16.6 22 -3.6 5.4-8.3 10.2-10 16.6 2.1-0.5 4.8-0.5 6-2.6 5.9-7.6 11.6-15.4 17.5-23 -1.2 5.1-1.4 10.5 0.4 15.5C645.6 526 640.7 529 639.1 534.3zM466.9 952.9c-0.3 2.1-0.6 4.3-0.8 6.5 -46.8 10.9-94.4 17.5-141.6 25.9 -14 2.4-28.1 4.5-42.3 6 -8 0.7-16 1.7-24 1.3 -6.3-0.3-12.6-0.5-18.8 0.3 -4.9 8.5-8.4 17.9-14.2 25.8 -3.9 5.5-10.4 8.5-16.8 9.8 -7.6 1.3-15.3-0.3-22.6-2.4 -2.4 11.3-3.6 22.9-4.1 34.5 -0.6 8.7 0.1 18.1-4.6 25.8 -4.3 6-10.3 11.3-17.6 13 -4.5 1.1-9.3-0.3-12.7-3.3 -6.2-6.5-10.3-15.9-8.2-25 2.4-12.6 9.5-23.8 17.7-33.5 3.7-4.4 6.1-9.7 8.1-15 -2.8-3.1-5.5-6.6-9-8.9 -3.1-0.5-6.1 0.7-8.5 2.5 -8.6 5.9-15 14.3-22.6 21.3 -6.4 6-14.1 10.4-22.1 14 -12.4 6.3-27.5 5.5-39.5-1.2 -1.7-0.9-3-2.9-2.3-4.8 2-8.8 7.3-17.1 15.6-21.2 16.5-8 30.4-20.6 47.5-27.4 6-2.2 12-4.7 17.4-8.1 -1.2-3.6-1.8-7.6-4.2-10.7 -3.6-2.4-8.2-1.9-12.3-2.3 -8.5-0.1-16.7-3.2-25.2-3.3 -10-0.8-20.2-1-29.6-4.5 -5.1-1.8-9.6-4.9-13.8-8.2 -4-3.1-7.6-7.2-8.5-12.3 -0.6-3 1.6-5.5 4-7.1 8.1-5.7 18.4-6.4 28-6.4 24.2 1.5 46.3 12.9 70 17.2 3.2 0.2 6.9 2.1 9.7-0.1 6.8-4.6 12.2-10.9 17.3-17.3 -7.3-7.8-15.3-15.3-20.2-24.9 -3.7-6.8-4.9-14.7-4-22.3 0.7-5.5 3-11.4 7.8-14.6 5.7-4.2 13.4-6.8 20.3-4.1 7.8 3.6 13.3 10.9 15.9 18.9 3.4 12.2-5.3 24.6-0.7 36.7 6.4 8.1 17.5 9.1 25.8 14.3 11.7 7.5 17.1 20.8 24.5 31.9 24.4-4.1 49.2-2.6 73.8-5.2 10.3-1.1 20.5-3.2 30.8-4.4 39.6-5 79.2-10.9 118.3-18.7C467.9 945.3 467.4 949.1 466.9 952.9zM330.8 431c-1.7 6.1 0.8 12.2 1.6 18.2 -4.9-5.9-8.5-12.7-12.7-19 -9.9-16.2-17-34-26.6-50.4 -9.3-16.4-20.1-31.8-30.9-47.2 -5.8-7.7-12.8-14.4-19.9-20.9 -6.5-5.9-12.4-12.3-18.8-18.3 -7.8-7.3-16.9-13-25.2-19.6 -13.3-10.5-29-17.3-44.8-23 -11.1-3.9-22.4-6.9-34-9 -11.7-2.1-23.8-1.8-35.1-5.7 -5.5-1.8-10.2-5.6-15.9-7.1 7.6 11.5 21.5 16.9 34.7 18.8 3.3 7.2 7 14.1 11.2 20.8 10.6 17 19.4 35 30 52 9.5 15.6 19 31.3 30.6 45.5 12.1 14.5 26.5 27 41.8 38.2 13.5 9.4 26.4 19.7 40.3 28.6 14.3 9.4 29 18.1 44.3 25.9 8.1 4 16.5 7.4 25.2 9.7 0.7 5.1 3.3 9.9 7.4 13.1 -1.6 2.8-2.6 6.3-5.6 8.1 -3.7 2.3-7.3 4.9-10.8 7.5 -1.4 1.1-2.8 2.3-4.2 3.4 -10.2-1.9-20.5-3.1-30.6-5.6 -20.1-5.1-39.1-14-57.4-23.6 -16-7.7-28.6-20.5-41.3-32.6 -6.7-6.7-14.2-12.5-20.5-19.6 -16.6-19.1-31.5-39.7-44.1-61.6 -5.5-10-12.2-19.3-17.9-29.1 -4-6.6-6.8-13.8-10.5-20.5 -9.2-18.2-20.5-35.7-25.3-55.7l-0.2-0.1c-2.1-6.5-3.7-13.1-6.6-19.2 -2.5-5.1-7.4-8.3-12.3-10.7 -6.4-3-11.8-7.7-16.7-12.6 2.6-2.7 5.6-5.6 9.5-6.3 14.4-2.8 29-5.1 43.8-5 10.5-0.3 20.7 1.9 31 3.3 12 1 23.9 3.3 35.5 6.4 18.4 4.3 35.8 12 52.8 20.3 7.3 3.7 14.4 8 20.7 13.3 15.5 13.3 32.8 25.1 45.3 41.6 5.1 6.9 11.1 13 16.5 19.7 6.3 7.6 10.7 16.5 16.4 24.5 10.3 14.7 16.3 31.8 24.2 47.8 7.3 14.6 12.1 30.1 16.8 45.6C338.1 423.3 332.6 425.8 330.8 431zM330.3 456.2c-1.4 2.2-2.7 4.4-4.1 6.6l-0.4-1c-15.9-4.5-30.5-12.7-44.9-20.8 -26-14.9-50.2-32.7-73.8-51.1 -6.7-5.3-13.6-10.4-19.4-16.7 -12.4-13.8-23.2-29.1-33.1-44.8 -11.7-17.7-20.8-37-32-55l-0.2 0c-5.3-8.2-10-16.8-13.6-25.8 23.9 2 46.9 9.8 68.2 20.5 13.1 7.1 24.6 16.7 36.3 25.8 15.3 12.5 30.4 25.6 42.8 41 17 21.7 31.8 45.1 44 69.9 3.8 7.6 7.1 15.5 11.4 22.8C317.1 437.5 323.8 446.8 330.3 456.2zM434.5 414.2c-0.8-0.1-2.5-0.3-3.4-0.4 -2.6-13.2-5.3-26.4-9.4-39.2 -2.4-7.8-5.8-15.2-8.5-22.9 -8-21.8-14.3-44.3-18.2-67.2 -5-25.2-3.5-51-1.4-76.4 1.3-11.2 2.1-22.4 5-33.4 6.6-22.7 16.8-44.5 31.3-63.3 4.4 8.3 7.1 17.5 9.3 26.7 3.3 13.3 7.9 26.3 12 39.4 6.2 21 11.4 42.4 14.3 64.1 1.4 9.2 1.6 18.6 0.6 27.9 -2.2 25.5-4.9 50.9-9.8 76.1 -4.4 22.3-10 44.6-19.4 65.5C436.1 412.2 435.2 413.2 434.5 414.2zM472.9 423.2c-3.3 0.4-6.5 1-9.6 1.8 -6.9-4.3-14.7-6.9-22.3-9.6 9.3-16.3 13.4-34.8 17.7-52.9 3.6-16.4 6.4-33 8.3-49.7 0.8-9.4 2.7-18.7 3.4-28.1 2.3-22.7 1.4-45.8-4.2-68 -5.5-23.3-12.1-46.3-19.6-69 -4.4-13.3-6.9-27.1-12.6-39.9 7.6-10.5 13-23.9 10.1-37 -0.8 0.5-1.3 1.2-1.5 2 -1.5 5.1-2.5 10.5-5 15.3 -4.9 9.9-12.8 17.9-18.8 27.2 -9.9 15.1-17.8 31.5-23.6 48.6 -2.6 7.8-5 15.7-5.8 23.9 -1.7 14.9-4.3 29.8-3.5 44.9 0.6 11-0.1 22.1 0.5 33.2 0.7 12.9 4.3 25.4 6.9 38 4.3 19.7 10.7 38.9 18 57.7 6.5 17 11.2 34.7 14.4 52.6 -0.8 0.1-2.5 0.2-3.3 0.3 -5.1-4.4-11.3-8.5-18.4-7.6 -10.1-17.7-21-35.1-28.3-54.1 -4.4-12-10-23.5-14.1-35.6 -3.6-9.7-4.9-20-7.9-29.9 -3.3-11.3-3.5-23.1-5.1-34.6 -4.2-22.9-0.5-46.1 0.8-69.1 1.8-14 6.8-27.2 11.4-40.4 5.4-15.2 13.4-29.3 21.7-43 5.1-8.4 11.8-15.7 17-24 11.7-18 28.8-31.5 46.1-43.9 2.9-2.2 6.7-2.1 10.2-2.2 0.5 7-0.1 14.2-2.3 21 -1.3 4.1-2 8.5-1.5 12.8 2.1 6.6 6.3 12.4 9.1 18.7 11.4 16.2 16.4 35.8 22.9 54.3 2.4 7.4 5.8 14.6 8 22.1 3.4 10.9 5.5 22.1 8.9 33 7.1 22.8 11.5 46.3 14.3 69.9 1.3 11 0.3 22 0.6 33 0.1 14.6 0.4 29.5-2.8 43.9 -5.3 19.1-10.9 38.2-19.9 56 -4.5 9.4-10.6 17.9-16.4 26.6C476.1 422.7 474.4 423.1 472.9 423.2z" class="a"></path><path d="M453.1 443.4c17.4-4 35.6 2.3 49.3 13.2 14.5 11.7 25.2 27.9 30.3 45.8 3.7 17.1 4.7 35.5-1.8 52 -3.6 9.1-9.9 16.8-17.2 23.3 2.1 0.5 4.1 1.1 6.2 1.7 3.4 1.1 6.7 2.6 9.7 4.6 5.5 3.9 10.1 8.8 14.2 14.1 7.4 10.3 8 24.5 2.8 35.9 -5.6 12.6-16.1 22.3-27.8 29.2 -9.6 5.7-20.1 9.4-30.3 13.7 -10.9 4.6-22.4 7.8-33.9 10.4 -11.1 2.5-22.7 3.5-34.1 1.9 -8.3-1.3-16.5-5.1-21.5-12.1 -6-8.6-10.6-19.5-8-30.1 1.6-7.5 3.2-15.4 7.9-21.7 1.6-2.3 3.4-4.4 5.2-6.6 -17.1 4.6-35.4-1.1-49-11.8 -4.8-3.6-8.6-8.2-12.4-12.8 -7.1-9.9-12.3-21.1-14.8-33 -1.8-11.6-1.5-23.7 2-35 5.1-16.1 17.9-30.1 34.6-34.3 17.4-4.4 35.7 2.6 48.9 13.9 -0.3-13.2 2.3-26.7 8.9-38.2C428.8 456 439.8 446.3 453.1 443.4zM434.6 457.3c-9.3 8.6-14 21.1-15.7 33.4 -2.5 21.7 3.9 44.1 16.7 61.7 8.7 12 20.5 22.3 34.8 26.9 5.8-0.2 11.3-2.2 17-3.1 6.7-1.4 13.5-0.8 20.2 0.1l0.4-0.5c15.4-9.6 21.9-28.7 22.2-46.1 0-23.3-9.3-46.6-25.3-63.5 -10.4-10.8-24.3-19.1-39.6-19.9C454.1 445.5 442.7 449.5 434.6 457.3zM355.7 498.8c-4.2 1.8-7.9 4.8-11.1 8.1 -11.3 12.1-14.7 29.8-12.8 45.8 2.4 20.3 12.8 39.7 29.1 52.2 13.7 10.5 33.6 15.4 49.3 6.5l0-0.1c7-4.4 13.8-9.7 17.4-17.4 5.4-10.3 7.6-22.4 6-33.9 -2.8-3.6-5.4-7.3-8.1-11 -4.1-7.2-7.1-14.9-9.6-22.8 -1.3-5.4-0.8-12.1-5.5-15.9 -8.2-8.1-18.8-14-30.3-15.8C372 493.6 363 494.4 355.7 498.8zM439.7 566.9c-0.6 9.5-2.4 19.2-7 27.7 2-1 4.1-2 6.1-3.1l0-0.2c5.9-2.8 11.7-5.5 17.9-7.6 1.6-0.5 3.3-1 5-1.4 -1.9-1.9-4.4-2.8-6.7-4.2C449.5 574.8 444.4 571.1 439.7 566.9zM483.9 582.3c-23 3.6-44.9 13.3-62.6 28.4 -11.6 7.7-20.4 19.6-24.2 33 -3 13.1 3.1 27.5 13.8 35.4 6.1 4.7 13.9 6.4 21.4 5.8 10 0.2 19.4-3.3 29.1-4.7 12.4-2.7 23.8-8.6 35.7-12.8 2-0.8 4.2-1.4 6-2.6 5.4-1.7 10.3-4.5 15.1-7.4 10.8-6.9 21.1-16.5 24.5-29.3 2.3-9.6 1.4-20.4-4.5-28.6 -6-8.3-15-14.5-25-16.6C503.6 580.9 493.4 579.3 483.9 582.3z" class="a"></path><path d="M467.8 507.2c4.6-1.4 9.2 1.5 12.4 4.6 6.7 6.9 10.7 16.3 11 25.9 0 4.2-0.7 8.9-4 11.9 -3 2.5-7.5 1.7-10.5-0.3 -6.2-3.9-10.3-10.3-12.7-17.1 -1.9-5.6-3.1-11.8-1.6-17.6C463 511.5 464.8 508.4 467.8 507.2zM475.6 517c-4.1 3.3-0.8 12.1 4.6 11.3C485.8 525.6 481.6 514.2 475.6 517z" class="a"></path><path d="M397.5 541.9c3.7-1.9 7.9 0.3 10.8 2.6 6.9 6 11.1 15 11.2 24.2 0 3.6-1.1 7.8-4.5 9.7 -3.1 1.3-6.7 0-9.3-1.9 -7.4-5.5-11.9-14.6-12.4-23.8C393.1 548.8 393.8 544.1 397.5 541.9zM405.8 549.2c-4.1 2.6-1.4 10 3.2 10.4C414.4 557.6 411 548.1 405.8 549.2z" class="a"></path><path d="M625.1 554.5c5.3-4.1 12.3-6.6 19.1-5.1 8.9 0.9 18.2 5.6 21.5 14.4 -3.5-0.5-6.7-2-9.6-3.9 -4.5-2.9-9.9-4.2-15.2-4.6 0.6 14.4 6.7 28 6.8 42.5 -0.3 11.2 0.4 22.5-2.2 33.4 -0.7 3.4-2.2 7.1-0.4 10.5 4.3 10.1 9.6 19.9 12.7 30.6 3.1 10.6 6.3 21.3 6.8 32.5 1.3 21.1-6 42.1-18.2 59.1 -7.8 10.7-17.6 19.9-28.3 27.7 -9 6.3-19.4 9.9-29.8 13.1 -8 2.8-16.8 1.8-24.9 4.3 0.1 2.1 0.4 4.2 0.7 6.3 -1.4 0.4-2.8 0.8-4.2 1.3 -0.7-3.4-2.8-7.3-0.4-10.4 3.5-3.4 8.7-2.9 13.1-3.9 0.7-4.9 0.7-10.2 3.7-14.4 3.2-4.5 8.3-6.8 13-9.3 -3.2-6.6-8.7-13.2-16.2-14.7 -7.9 2.9-15.6 6.3-23.6 8.7 -3.2-5-3.4-11-3.8-16.7 -19.5 7.6-39 15.6-59.3 20.6 -24.2 4.6-48.5 8.7-73.2 9 -19.4 0.1-39.2-0.8-57.5-7.9 -11.5-4.3-22.3-10.2-32.5-16.8 -14.5-8.7-25.6-21.9-35.8-35.2 -2.6-3.3-4.2-7.3-4.9-11.4 3.2 1.8 5.1 5 7.5 7.7 9.8 11.6 20.3 22.8 33 31.3 16.8 11.7 36 19.9 56.1 23.9 33.2 5.8 67.1 1.3 99.9-4.9 20.6-3.9 40.2-11.7 59.5-19.8 19.6-8.8 37.1-21.8 52.9-36.2 16.5-15 28.7-34.2 37.6-54.5 4.3-9.1 8-18.6 9.1-28.6 2.7-13.9 3.6-28.1 2.5-42.2 -1.4-11.4-4.4-22.5-7.4-33.5 -4 2.1-7.8 4.7-12.1 6.4C621 560 622.4 556.6 625.1 554.5zM642.9 649.4c-2.4 7.5-6.2 14.5-10.1 21.4 4.1 5.2 8.4 10.4 12.4 15.7 4.3 5.9 9 11.5 13.8 17 -1.1-8.9-3.1-17.6-5.4-26.2C650.9 667.7 648.2 657.9 642.9 649.4zM623.5 688.8c-5.6 8.1-11 16.2-17.6 23.6 -4.2 5-9.5 9-14.4 13.4 4.3 7.2 8.8 14.3 12.8 21.7 17.8-6.7 35.8-12.8 53-20.8 0.6-4.6 1.4-9.1 1.9-13.7 -6-7.5-10.9-15.8-17.4-23 -3.6-4.6-7.3-9.3-11.2-13.6C627.9 680.2 626.3 684.8 623.5 688.8zM551.3 752.8c0.5 4.3 1.1 8.5 1.5 12.8 15.6-4.3 30.7-10.5 45.9-16.1 -3.5-7.2-7.5-14-11.7-20.7C575.8 737.7 564.3 746.6 551.3 752.8zM602.4 752l0 0.4c-7 1.4-13.3 4.6-20.1 6.8 4.3 3.5 8.8 7 11.5 12 0.9 1.4 1.3 3.2 2.5 4.5 3.2-0.7 6.2-2.1 9.3-3.2l-0.2-0.4c8.9-3.6 19.1-5.1 28.3-1.7 9.6-10.2 16.6-22.9 20.3-36.5C636.5 739.1 619.7 746.3 602.4 752zM609.7 775.9c-6 3.1-8.4 10.3-14.6 13.1 -0.4-3.4 0.9-6.5 2.5-9.5 -5.6 0.9-11.4 2.8-15.1 7.3 -3.7 4.1-4.4 9.8-4.5 15.1 19.5-2.5 38.5-11.4 51.8-26C623.5 772.8 615.7 772.1 609.7 775.9z" class="a"></path><path d="M601.8 601.4c2.8-1.4 4.9 3.4 1.9 4.5C600.9 607.2 598.7 602.4 601.8 601.4z" class="a"></path><path d="M571.7 619c2.8-1.8 6.8 1.4 5.9 4.6 -0.5 2.7-4.3 3.9-6.3 2.1C568.9 624.2 569.3 620.4 571.7 619z" class="a"></path><path d="M597.5 631.9c3.2-1.4 5.9 4 2.5 5.5C596.5 639.4 593.5 633.3 597.5 631.9z" class="a"></path><path d="M380.6 700.1c3.2-1.2 6.7 2.7 4.9 5.7 -1.3 2.9-6.1 2.7-7.3-0.1C377.2 703.5 378.4 700.8 380.6 700.1z" class="a"></path><path d="M339.7 716.3c2.5-2.4 5.5 2.6 2.6 3.9C340 722 337.6 717.8 339.7 716.3z" class="a"></path><path d="M371.5 733.9c3.6-1.6 5.6 4.9 1.8 5.7C369.9 740.7 368.1 734.9 371.5 733.9z" class="a"></path><path d="M445.8 32.2c2.9-2.2 6.7-2.1 10.2-2.2 0.5 7-0.1 14.2-2.3 21 -1.3 4.1-2 8.5-1.5 12.8 2.1 6.6 6.3 12.4 9.1 18.7 4.7 13.8 10.2 27.4 13.7 41.6 1.3 6.2 4.6 11.6 6.7 17.5 7.2 18.4 12.3 37.5 16.2 56.8 4.6 24.8 7.7 50.1 7.9 75.4 0.4 22.4 0 44.8-3.5 67 -3.8 25-9.7 50.2-22.6 72.2 -2.2 3.4-4.8 6.7-6.6 10.4 -3.3 0.4-6.5 1-9.6 1.8 -6.9-4.3-14.7-6.9-22.3-9.6 9.3-16.3 13.4-34.8 17.7-52.9 3.6-16.4 6.4-33 8.3-49.7 0.8-9.4 2.7-18.7 3.4-28.1 2.3-22.7 1.4-45.8-4.2-68 -5.5-23.3-12.1-46.3-19.6-69 -4.4-13.3-6.9-27.1-12.6-39.9 7.6-10.5 13-23.9 10.1-37 -0.8 0.5-1.3 1.2-1.5 2 -1.5 5.1-2.5 10.5-5 15.3 -4.9 9.9-12.8 17.9-18.8 27.2 -9.9 15.1-17.8 31.5-23.6 48.6 -2.6 7.8-5 15.7-5.8 23.9 -1.7 14.9-4.3 29.8-3.5 44.9 0.6 11-0.1 22.1 0.5 33.2 0.7 12.9 4.3 25.4 6.9 38 4.3 19.7 10.7 38.9 18 57.7 6.5 17 11.2 34.7 14.4 52.6 -0.8 0.1-2.5 0.2-3.3 0.3 -5.1-4.4-11.3-8.5-18.4-7.6 -10.1-17.7-21-35.1-28.3-54.1 -4.4-12-10-23.5-14.1-35.6 -3.6-9.7-4.9-20-7.9-29.9 -3.3-11.3-3.5-23.1-5.1-34.6 -4.2-22.9-0.5-46.1 0.8-69.1 1.8-14 6.8-27.2 11.4-40.4 5.4-15.2 13.4-29.3 21.7-43 5.1-8.4 11.8-15.7 17-24C411.4 58.1 428.5 44.5 445.8 32.2z" class="b"></path><path d="M39.5 203.4c14.4-2.8 29-5.1 43.8-5 10.5-0.3 20.7 1.9 31 3.3 12 1 23.9 3.3 35.5 6.4 18.4 4.3 35.8 12 52.8 20.3 7.3 3.7 14.4 8 20.7 13.3 15.5 13.3 32.8 25.1 45.3 41.6 5.1 6.9 11.1 13 16.5 19.7 6.3 7.6 10.7 16.5 16.4 24.5 10.3 14.7 16.3 31.8 24.2 47.8 7.3 14.6 12.1 30.1 16.8 45.6 -4.5 2.5-10 5-11.8 10.3 -1.7 6.1 0.8 12.2 1.6 18.2 -4.9-5.9-8.5-12.7-12.7-19 -9.9-16.2-17-34-26.6-50.4 -9.3-16.4-20.1-31.8-30.9-47.2 -5.8-7.7-12.8-14.4-19.9-20.9 -6.5-5.9-12.4-12.3-18.8-18.3 -7.8-7.3-16.9-13-25.2-19.6 -13.3-10.5-29-17.3-44.8-23 -11.1-3.9-22.4-6.9-34-9 -11.7-2.1-23.8-1.8-35.1-5.7 -5.5-1.8-10.2-5.6-15.9-7.1 7.6 11.5 21.5 16.9 34.7 18.8 3.3 7.2 7 14.1 11.2 20.8 10.6 17 19.4 35 30 52 9.5 15.6 19 31.3 30.6 45.5 12.1 14.5 26.5 27 41.8 38.2 13.5 9.4 26.4 19.7 40.3 28.6 14.3 9.4 29 18.1 44.3 25.9 8.1 4 16.5 7.4 25.2 9.7 0.7 5.1 3.3 9.9 7.4 13.1 -1.6 2.8-2.6 6.3-5.6 8.1 -3.7 2.3-7.3 4.9-10.8 7.5 -20.4-2-39.5-9.9-57.5-19.2 -25.5-13.8-49-31.1-70.4-50.6 -5.2-5.5-11.3-10-16.5-15.5 -26.9-27.7-51.2-58.3-69.5-92.5 -5.1-9.7-9.1-19.9-14.8-29.3 -3-5.4-6-10.9-8.3-16.7 -1.5-3.9-3.6-7.5-6.3-10.8 -2.9-3.4-4.8-7.7-8.5-10.3l-0.2-0.1c-2.1-6.5-3.7-13.1-6.6-19.2 -2.5-5.1-7.4-8.3-12.3-10.7 -6.4-3-11.8-7.7-16.7-12.6C32.6 206.9 35.5 204 39.5 203.4z" class="b"></path><path d="M401.6 414c4.9-1.8 10.2 0.2 14.5 2.6 1.1 7.7 2.8 15.3 3.3 23.1 11.1-1.4 21.6-6.2 32.9-5.6 6.7 0.3 13.4 0.4 20 1.7 8.4 1.8 17.1 2.3 25.6 3.3 10.8 1.5 21.5 4.1 31.4 8.6 5 2.2 9.5 5.3 14.4 7.6 13.5 6.1 25 17 31.7 30.3 0.9 2.4 3.8 1.6 5.9 1.8 12.5-0.3 25.1 1.1 37 4.9 -2.8 6.6-5 13.4-7.4 20.1 -9.8 3.6-17.7 10.5-25.8 16.9 -20.8 15.6-40.4 33.2-55.5 54.5 -3-2-6.3-3.5-9.7-4.6 2.3-3.3 5.3-6.1 7.8-9.3 10.3-15 13.7-34.3 10.3-52 -1-5.4-1.9-11.1-5.2-15.6 -5.1-17.9-15.9-34.1-30.3-45.8 -13.6-10.9-31.9-17.1-49.3-13.2 -13.3 2.9-24.3 12.6-30.9 24.2 -6.6 11.5-9.1 25-8.9 38.2 -13.2-11.3-31.5-18.3-48.9-13.9 -16.7 4.1-29.5 18.2-34.6 34.3 -3.5 11.3-3.8 23.4-2 35 2.5 11.9 7.8 23.1 14.8 33 0 2.7 1.7 4.8 3.4 6.7 7.6 9.7 17.9 17.3 29.5 21.4 7.4 2.9 15.5 2.7 23.3 3.1 -4.8 6.3-6.3 14.1-7.9 21.7 -25.1-5-51.1-4.9-76.4-1 -7.3 1.4-14.9 2-21.9 4.8 -9-2.9-17.9-5.7-27.1-7.8 4.5-16.1 3.3-33 5.7-49.4 1-10.9 4.6-21.3 7.2-31.9 3.9-10.5 7.8-21.3 14.8-30.3 9.3-12 21.2-21.8 33.2-30.9 0.8 1.8 1.5 3.7 2.2 5.7 8.2-8.2 15.6-17.9 26.3-23 7.5-3.4 15.1-7.2 20.9-13.1 2.2-2.2 2.5-5.5 3-8.4 -4.9 2.6-9.5 6-14 9.2 -3.5-3.4-7.2-6.6-10.7-10 -6.8 4.2-12.9 9.6-17.5 16.2 -2.3-3.2-5.8-7-4.4-11.3 2.4-5.5 8.5-7.9 13.9-9.3 9.8-1.8 19.8-0.9 29.6-2.9 -10.4-7.3-23.6-4.1-35.4-4.3 -1.8-4.1-5.3-8.8-3.1-13.5 3.3-7.8 11.9-12.1 20.1-11.9 11.5-0.1 22.5 4.6 31.8 11 4.5 3.1 7.7 7.7 12.4 10.6 2.3 1.5 5.3 0.8 7.9 0.7 -4.3-5.5-10.8-9.2-14-15.6C392.2 424.7 395.1 416.1 401.6 414z" class="b"></path><path d="M617.7 506.8c1.8-5.2 3.7-10.3 6-15.3 5.9 1.8 12.1 2.3 17.9 4.5C633.5 499.3 625.9 503.8 617.7 506.8z" class="b"></path><path d="M441.4 573.5c5.1 3.4 9.7 7.4 15.2 10.1 -6.2 2.1-12 4.9-17.9 7.6C439.4 585.3 440.8 579.5 441.4 573.5z" class="b"></path><path d="M263.6 648.7c0.3-1.8 2.1-0.7 3.3-0.6 4.7 1.1 9.4 2.4 14 3.9 -6.8 3.6-14.4 4.9-21.6 7.5C261 656 262.1 652.3 263.6 648.7z" class="b"></path><path d="M625.9 859c19.2-9.4 38.2-19.9 54.6-33.7 -0.2 19.1-0.1 38.2-0.1 57.3C663.5 872.2 645.4 863.5 625.9 859z" class="b"></path><path d="M159.7 872.2c5.7-4.2 13.4-6.8 20.3-4.1 7.8 3.6 13.3 10.9 15.9 18.9 3.4 12.2-5.3 24.6-0.7 36.7 6.4 8.1 17.5 9.1 25.8 14.3 11.7 7.5 17.1 20.8 24.5 31.9 24.4-4.1 49.2-2.6 73.8-5.2 10.3-1.1 20.5-3.2 30.8-4.4 39.6-5 79.2-10.9 118.3-18.7 -0.5 3.8-1 7.6-1.5 11.4 -8.3 1.4-16.4 4-24.6 5.7 -23.4 5.2-47.1 8.7-70.9 10.9 -12.8 1.9-25.9 1.6-38.4 4.8 -32.9 7-66.5 10.8-100.2 11.6 -2.2 17.9-18 32.2-35.5 34.7 -4.7 0.5-9.4 0.2-14.1 0.1 -1.2 5.5-1.8 11.1-3.4 16.5 -1.8 5.7-0.8 11.8-1.7 17.6 -1.7 10.3-4.8 20.5-10.1 29.6 -2.8 4.4-6.1 8.8-10.9 11.2 -3.1 1.8-6.9 0.9-10.2 0.6 -6.2-6.5-10.3-15.9-8.2-25 2.4-12.6 9.5-23.8 17.7-33.5 3.7-4.4 6.1-9.7 8.1-15 -2.8-3.1-5.5-6.6-9-8.9 -3.1-0.5-6.1 0.7-8.5 2.5 -8.6 5.9-15 14.3-22.6 21.3 -6.4 6-14.1 10.4-22.1 14 -12.4 6.3-27.5 5.5-39.5-1.2 -1.7-0.9-3-2.9-2.3-4.8 2-8.8 7.3-17.1 15.6-21.2 16.5-8 30.4-20.6 47.5-27.4 6-2.2 12-4.7 17.4-8.1 -1.2-3.6-1.8-7.6-4.2-10.7 -3.6-2.4-8.2-1.9-12.3-2.3 -8.5-0.1-16.7-3.2-25.2-3.3 -10-0.8-20.2-1-29.6-4.5 -5.1-1.8-9.6-4.9-13.8-8.2 -4-3.1-7.6-7.2-8.5-12.3 -0.6-3 1.6-5.5 4-7.1 8.1-5.7 18.4-6.4 28-6.4 24.2 1.5 46.3 12.9 70 17.2 3.2 0.2 6.9 2.1 9.7-0.1 6.8-4.6 12.2-10.9 17.3-17.3 -7.3-7.8-15.3-15.3-20.2-24.9 -3.7-6.8-4.9-14.7-4-22.3C152.6 881.2 154.9 875.4 159.7 872.2z" class="b"></path><path d="M524.7 902.1c8.6-3.1 16.9-7 25.6-9.9 -3.9 11-7.8 22-10 33.4 -4.6 22.5-6.6 45.8-4.6 68.7 4 36.7 18.2 72.6 41.8 101.2 11.9 14.5 27 26.2 44.2 33.7 18.4 7.9 38.8 10.5 58.7 9.7 0 2.1 0 4.2 0.1 6.3 -13.6 2.1-27.4 3.1-41.2 2.9 -37.1-0.6-75-8.8-106.4-29.2 -24.6-15.8-43-40.5-51.6-68.3 -7.3-22.5-9.3-46.5-8.7-70 0.9-23.5 4.3-46.8 10.1-69.6C497 909.8 511.2 906.8 524.7 902.1z" class="b"></path><path d="M532.7 502.3c3.3 4.6 4.2 10.2 5.2 15.6 3.5 17.8 0.1 37-10.3 52 -2.5 3.2-5.4 6-7.8 9.3 -2.1-0.6-4.2-1.2-6.2-1.7 7.2-6.5 13.5-14.2 17.2-23.3C537.4 537.8 536.4 519.4 532.7 502.3z" class="c"></path><path d="M439.7 566.9c4.7 4.2 9.8 7.9 15.3 11.1 2.2 1.3 4.7 2.3 6.7 4.2 -1.7 0.5-3.3 0.9-5 1.4 -5.5-2.7-10.2-6.7-15.2-10.1 -0.6 5.9-2.1 11.8-2.7 17.7l0 0.2c-2 1.1-4 2.1-6.1 3.1C437.2 586.1 439.1 576.4 439.7 566.9z" class="c"></path><path d="M346.1 600.8c-1.7-1.9-3.3-4.1-3.4-6.7 3.8 4.5 7.6 9.2 12.4 12.8 13.6 10.7 31.9 16.4 49 11.8 -1.8 2.2-3.6 4.3-5.2 6.6 -7.8-0.4-15.9-0.2-23.3-3.1C364 618.1 353.7 610.5 346.1 600.8z" class="c"></path><path d="M645.2 686.4c2.9-3 5.6-6.1 8.5-9.2 2.3 8.6 4.3 17.3 5.4 26.2C654.2 697.9 649.6 692.3 645.2 686.4z" class="h"></path><path d="M641.6 496c3.1-1.3 6.2-2.5 9.3-4 0.3 0.5 0.8 1.4 1.1 1.8 -5.5 7.4-11.3 14.4-16.6 22 -3.6 5.4-8.3 10.2-10 16.6 2.1-0.5 4.8-0.5 6-2.6 5.9-7.6 11.6-15.4 17.5-23 -1.2 5.1-1.4 10.5 0.4 15.5 -3.7 3.7-8.6 6.7-10.2 12 5.5-0.4 8.8-5.1 12.6-8.4 7.9 9.4 18.2 16.5 28.7 22.8 0 89.1 0.1 178.3-0.1 267.4 -14 12.5-30.5 21.8-47.1 30.3 -11.4 5.8-22.3 12.5-34.2 17.2 -25.5 11.3-51.1 22.5-77.4 31.7 -22.1 7.4-45.3 10.7-68.5 12.7 -7.3 0.7-14.6 1.2-21.9 0.7 -16.1-0.8-32.3-1.9-47.8-6.3 -7-2-14.1-3.5-20.9-6.1 -11-3.8-22.3-7.4-31.8-14.3 -6.2-4.5-12.7-8.6-18.4-13.7 -6.4-5.9-13.3-11.2-19.4-17.5 -5.1-5-9.1-10.9-13.9-16.2 -6.2-6.9-12.6-13.6-17.5-21.5 -11-16-20-33.8-23.8-53.1 -1.3-6.8-2.9-13.6-4.3-20.4 -1.9-12.8 0.5-25.8 3.4-38.2 16.3-5.9 33.4-8.7 50.3-12.3 1.7-0.4 3.5-0.9 4.4-2.5 -0.3-2.2-3-1.2-4.4-1.3 -16.5 2.5-33 5.7-49 10.4 2.5-6 5.7-11.8 8.6-17.6 13.4-1.1 26.8-0.8 40.2-0.9 4.2-0.1 9 0.7 12.2-2.6 -3.1-2.7-7.4-2.1-11.2-2.3 -12.2-0.4-24.4-0.6-36.6-0.2 2.9-4 5.7-8.2 7.7-12.7 7.1-2.6 14.8-4 21.6-7.5 9 2.4 17.8 5.6 26.6 8.6 2.4 0.8 5 1.8 7.6 0.9 0.3-1.2 0-2.1-1.2-2.5 -6.8-3.6-14.2-5.4-21.3-8.2 7-2.8 14.6-3.4 21.9-4.8 25.3-4 51.3-4.1 76.4 1 -2.7 10.7 2 21.5 8 30.1 4.9 7 13.2 10.8 21.5 12.1 11.3 1.6 22.9 0.6 34.1-1.9 11.5-2.6 23-5.8 33.9-10.4 10.2-4.3 20.8-8 30.3-13.7 11.7-6.9 22.2-16.6 27.8-29.2 5.3-11.4 4.7-25.6-2.8-35.9 -4.1-5.3-8.7-10.3-14.2-14.1 15.1-21.3 34.7-39 55.5-54.5 8-6.4 16-13.3 25.8-16.9 -1.4 4-2.6 8-3.8 12 -1.3 4.2-2.9 8.5-2.3 13.1 1.5-1.2 3.4-2.3 4-4.3 3-8.8 5.6-17.7 8.9-26.4C625.9 503.8 633.5 499.3 641.6 496zM625.1 554.5c-2.8 2.1-4.1 5.5-3.9 8.9 4.2-1.7 8-4.3 12.1-6.4 3 11 5.9 22.1 7.4 33.5 1.1 14.1 0.2 28.3-2.5 42.2 -1.1 10-4.8 19.5-9.1 28.6 -8.9 20.3-21.1 39.5-37.6 54.5 -15.8 14.5-33.3 27.5-52.9 36.2 -19.3 8-38.9 15.9-59.5 19.8 -32.8 6.2-66.7 10.7-99.9 4.9 -20.1-4-39.3-12.2-56.1-23.9 -12.7-8.5-23.2-19.7-33-31.3 -2.4-2.6-4.3-5.9-7.5-7.7 0.7 4.1 2.3 8.1 4.9 11.4 10.2 13.3 21.3 26.4 35.8 35.2 10.3 6.6 21.1 12.5 32.5 16.8 18.2 7.1 38.1 8 57.5 7.9 24.7-0.2 49-4.4 73.2-9 20.4-5 39.8-13 59.3-20.6 0.5 5.7 0.7 11.7 3.8 16.7 8-2.5 15.8-5.9 23.6-8.7 7.5 1.6 12.9 8.1 16.2 14.7 -4.7 2.5-9.9 4.8-13 9.3 -2.9 4.2-3 9.5-3.7 14.4 -4.4 0.9-9.6 0.5-13.1 3.9 -2.5 3.1-0.3 7.1 0.4 10.4 1.4-0.5 2.8-0.9 4.2-1.3 -0.3-2.1-0.5-4.2-0.7-6.3 8.1-2.5 16.8-1.5 24.9-4.3 10.4-3.2 20.8-6.9 29.8-13.1 10.8-7.7 20.5-16.9 28.3-27.7 12.2-17 19.4-38 18.2-59.1 -0.5-11.1-3.7-21.9-6.8-32.5 -3.1-10.6-8.4-20.4-12.7-30.6 -1.8-3.4-0.3-7.1 0.4-10.5 2.6-10.9 2-22.3 2.2-33.4 -0.1-14.5-6.2-28.1-6.8-42.5 5.3 0.5 10.6 1.7 15.2 4.6 2.9 1.9 6.1 3.3 9.6 3.9 -3.3-8.8-12.7-13.5-21.5-14.4C637.5 547.9 630.5 550.4 625.1 554.5zM601.8 601.4c-3.1 1-0.9 5.9 1.9 4.5C606.7 604.7 604.6 600 601.8 601.4zM571.7 619c-2.4 1.3-2.9 5.1-0.4 6.7 2.1 1.8 5.8 0.6 6.3-2.1C578.6 620.4 574.6 617.3 571.7 619zM597.5 631.9c-4 1.4-1 7.5 2.5 5.5C603.4 635.9 600.8 630.5 597.5 631.9zM380.6 700.1c-2.2 0.7-3.4 3.4-2.3 5.5 1.2 2.9 6 3 7.3 0.1C387.3 702.8 383.8 698.8 380.6 700.1zM339.7 716.3c-2.1 1.5 0.3 5.7 2.6 3.9C345.1 718.9 342.2 713.9 339.7 716.3zM371.5 733.9c-3.5 1-1.6 6.8 1.8 5.7C377.1 738.8 375.1 732.3 371.5 733.9z" class="i"></path><path d="M598.5 871.7c9-4.4 18.1-8.8 27.4-12.7 19.4 4.4 37.6 13.1 54.5 23.6 0 85.4 0 170.8 0 256.3 -19.9 0.9-40.3-1.8-58.7-9.7 -17.2-7.5-32.3-19.3-44.2-33.7 -23.6-28.6-37.8-64.4-41.8-101.2 -2.1-23-0.1-46.2 4.6-68.7 2.3-11.5 6.1-22.5 10-33.4C566.5 885.6 582.3 878.2 598.5 871.7z" class="i"></path><path d="M421.3 610.7c17.7-15.1 39.7-24.9 62.6-28.4 8.4 1.9 17.3 2 25.4 5.4 7.4 3.3 15.3 7.1 19.8 14.3 5.3 7.7 6.2 17.9 3.2 26.6 -4.8 15.3-16.9 26.6-29.1 36.3 -1.8 1.2-4 1.8-6 2.6 -12 4.1-23.3 10.1-35.7 12.8 -9.8 1.4-19.2 4.9-29.1 4.7 -7.5 0.6-15.4-1.1-21.4-5.8 -10.7-7.9-16.8-22.3-13.8-35.4C400.8 630.3 409.6 618.4 421.3 610.7zM453 600.3c-9.2 4.3-18.1 9.5-25.3 16.7 -1.6 1.7-3.5 4.1-2.5 6.5 3.2 2.4 7.5 1.6 11.2 1.1 14.1-2.8 27.5-8.6 39.5-16.4 5.6-3.9 12.2-7.8 14.3-14.8 -2.9-2.9-7.2-2.2-10.8-1.8C470.1 592.9 461.5 596.6 453 600.3z" fill="#ED5E87"></path><path d="M483.9 582.3c9.5-3 19.7-1.4 29.2 0.7 10 2.1 19.1 8.3 25 16.6 5.9 8.1 6.7 19 4.5 28.6 -3.3 12.8-13.6 22.4-24.5 29.3 -4.8 2.8-9.7 5.7-15.1 7.4 12.2-9.6 24.3-21 29.1-36.3 3-8.8 2.1-18.9-3.2-26.6 -4.5-7.2-12.3-11-19.8-14.3C501.2 584.2 492.3 584.1 483.9 582.3z" fill="#DC3C6A"></path><path d="M582.3 759.2c6.7-2.2 13.1-5.4 20.1-6.8 -1.2 6.7-0.3 13.6 3 19.6l0.2 0.4c-3.1 1.1-6.1 2.5-9.3 3.2 -1.2-1.3-1.6-3-2.5-4.5C591.1 766.2 586.6 762.7 582.3 759.2z" fill="#B54F7C"></path><path d="M609.7 775.9c6.1-3.8 13.8-3 20 0.1 -13.3 14.6-32.3 23.5-51.8 26 0.1-5.3 0.8-11 4.5-15.1 3.7-4.5 9.5-6.5 15.1-7.3 -1.5 2.9-2.9 6.1-2.5 9.5C601.3 786.2 603.7 778.9 609.7 775.9z" fill="#F396BE"></path><path d="M602.4 752c17.3-5.7 34.1-12.9 51.5-18.2 -3.7 13.5-10.6 26.3-20.3 36.5 -9.2-3.4-19.4-1.9-28.3 1.7 -3.3-6-4.2-13-3-19.6L602.4 752z" fill="#933361"></path></svg>
```

Comment: @MaximLensky в целом да, я вечерком прикручу к этому flubber и будет вполне анимация (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/940478/188366)

Comment: ты не понял ...глазик должен моргать же а не шарик туда сюда :))

Comment: @MaximLensky в целом я хотел показать как достучаться до нужного path из любой картинки...

Comment: ааа...ну плюсик тебе поставил так как твои способности уникальны ...приятно иметь дело с профессионалом

Comment: @StrangerintheQ В `Firefox` не работает. В `Chrome` интересно смотрится (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT сейчас посмотрел - css параметры не работают, жаль придется в атрибуты устанавливать значения.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ты по 4 часа в сутки спишь? Пять часов назад правил и уже опять в строю :))

Comment: @Alexandr_TT ну не по 4, но 6 для меня почти что норма, но вчера что-то и впрямь засиделся

Comment: @Alexandr_TT а то что css transition для атрибутов в firefox не работает это как-то можно обойти? починил, но в мозилле анимация не работает

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в Firefox работает сейчас анимация глаз, проверил В частности CSS анимацию атрибута "d"  `cx` `cy` и другиx поддерживает только `Chrome`  в своей экспериментальной технологии. Можно частично отказаться от css-animation и заменить `smill`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT починил FF

Comment: @StrangerintheQ,а можете сделать чтобы анимация шла автоматически а не при клике мышкой?

Comment: @Ivan912 запросто, как часто?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ,раз в 3 секунды

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  у вас получилось? или тут циклично не возможно сделать?

Comment: @Ivan912 у меня работает

Comment: спасибо огромное

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я вам кое что написал на эмел который с ютуба взял

Comment: Самый реалистичный вариант )

Comment: @ʞɔᴉNɹǝꓥ спасибо =)

Answer (score 3):

Это пример анимации кролика но саму картинку я взял из сети :[с этого сайта](https://svgsilh.com/ru/image/2025993.html)

Так же анимировал по технике анимации SMIL

```html
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
viewBox="0 0 1460 1880"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<g transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M7465 12781 c-206 -74 -565 -358 -1135 -897 -433 -408 -844 -865
-1110 -1231 -40 -57 -75 -101 -77 -99 -2 2 -23 68 -48 147 -100 326 -245 709
-348 914 -180 362 -327 487 -577 487 -183 1 -334 -74 -510 -251 -384 -387
-558 -881 -660 -1871 -63 -615 -123 -1818 -119 -2382 0 -92 -3 -172 -7 -179
-12 -19 -221 -114 -334 -152 -58 -19 -195 -56 -305 -82 -329 -77 -413 -108
-565 -210 -120 -80 -214 -167 -336 -308 -183 -212 -290 -389 -353 -582 -33
-102 -64 -255 -117 -565 -77 -458 -145 -682 -301 -994 -80 -159 -157 -284
-309 -502 -165 -236 -209 -310 -236 -398 -41 -133 -13 -219 127 -394 84 -106
147 -202 177 -270 11 -26 53 -144 93 -262 40 -119 87 -246 103 -282 88 -194
244 -348 421 -417 65 -26 69 -26 311 -23 190 2 267 -1 345 -14 96 -16 152 -16
301 2 l51 6 12 -48 c19 -73 52 -153 182 -435 227 -494 333 -686 500 -910 139
-184 471 -569 492 -569 11 0 13 -4 -132 205 -243 350 -403 607 -521 840 -154
301 -217 508 -276 906 l-5 35 133 12 c330 28 668 114 873 221 38 20 137 83
220 141 194 135 316 197 501 255 366 114 501 168 686 271 382 214 748 538 958
850 151 223 271 582 270 807 -1 78 -6 69 -65 -108 -55 -166 -169 -403 -255
-532 -189 -282 -468 -517 -828 -697 -273 -137 -518 -213 -948 -296 -685 -132
-778 -168 -1122 -429 -190 -144 -293 -195 -472 -234 -85 -19 -119 -21 -320
-17 -397 8 -505 5 -636 -19 -229 -40 -282 -27 -360 90 -53 80 -264 509 -292
593 -25 75 -20 90 27 82 93 -15 206 -99 406 -302 152 -155 202 -195 217 -171
13 21 9 72 -17 191 -32 148 -32 215 -1 281 33 69 74 114 265 288 198 181 471
462 494 509 14 28 14 33 2 36 -38 9 -169 -86 -509 -365 -347 -286 -465 -361
-580 -370 -235 -19 -511 197 -582 455 -15 54 -16 74 -7 127 12 68 9 63 588
1210 274 544 309 619 380 827 52 150 73 246 115 515 46 299 84 398 201 514
120 119 261 167 624 214 290 38 418 71 530 135 28 16 111 77 185 134 216 169
371 253 673 365 76 28 208 72 294 96 365 105 533 111 701 26 74 -37 146 -94
312 -245 253 -230 344 -293 434 -303 35 -4 47 -1 74 22 87 73 107 184 122 685
18 586 38 846 85 1129 134 789 419 1501 880 2196 120 181 327 464 390 533 106
118 99 19 -56 -833 -251 -1382 -415 -1953 -857 -2996 -86 -204 -125 -318 -153
-452 -19 -91 -22 -131 -20 -377 1 -363 16 -670 36 -743 59 -226 219 -308 770
-397 318 -52 671 -68 885 -41 224 28 477 89 820 198 96 31 197 62 223 70 76
23 47 26 -39 4 -196 -50 -614 -118 -939 -153 -186 -20 -646 -17 -765 5 -120
22 -272 74 -347 118 -96 57 -185 155 -238 262 -68 138 -88 225 -89 387 -1 199
37 323 165 546 214 373 535 1236 748 2015 128 469 230 993 361 1859 109 723
144 892 251 1213 59 177 72 273 44 331 -31 65 -89 80 -180 47z m-3270 -876
c46 -27 71 -58 112 -141 78 -155 138 -391 294 -1164 44 -217 96 -456 116 -530
49 -188 49 -175 8 -270 -52 -122 -121 -326 -156 -462 -56 -223 -81 -421 -99
-773 -27 -531 -72 -602 -429 -686 -457 -107 -516 -127 -829 -286 -112 -57
-206 -103 -209 -103 -3 0 -2 15 2 33 3 17 10 478 15 1022 8 955 12 1090 45
1420 42 408 115 782 205 1040 46 133 158 356 238 475 243 364 509 528 687 425z"/>

<path d="">
  <animate 
   attributeName="d"
   dur="1s" 
   repeatCount="indefinite"
    values="M 4379.5402,6012.1314 C 4540.5157,5168.8032 2367.525,5413.8361 3760,5379 c 148,-19 288,19 417,114 109,81 171,182 246,403 -109.3454,355.5504 -20.6455,-339.2546 -43.4598,116.1314 z;
 M 4379.5402,6012.1314 C 3644.5684,6282.6836 2221.7581,5595.0598 3760,5379 c 148,-19 288,19 417,114 109,81 171,182 246,403 -109.3454,355.5504 -20.6455,-339.2546 -43.4598,116.1314 z"
  />
</path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Пример рекомендуется к просмотру в полноэкранном режиме

Comment: для реалистичности я бы зрачок  в глаз добавил и к анимации добавил `keyTimes`  и`keysplines` (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я это не разу ни делал .. покажи ...:))

Comment: Генератор` keyTimes`  https://svg-art.ru/?p=1674 двигаешь красные контрольные точки и копируешь значения. Внизу пример с желтым смайликом, который моргает глазом

Comment: @Alexandr_TT чё то после keytimes перестала работать анимация

Comment: ну значит, где-то с синтаксисом ошибся. Примеры видел на сайте, всё работает. Хочешь, попробую  сделать здесь на твоем примере?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT давай, я просто хоть увидеть хочу что это такое ..

Comment: заглядывай, буду делать, надеюсь что не вылезут какие-нибудь проблемы. SVG, - сам понимаешь :)))

Comment: готово, но глазик смотрится с перевернутым веком. Надо патч его перерисовывать, но поленился, тебе ведь главное принцип понять хотелось?