# Как анимировать SVG с помощью ванильного JS?

Tags: javascript, html5, svg, svg-animation

Только начал открывать для себя SVG изучая немногочисленные туториалы.
Разобрался, что существует три способа анимации: SMIL, CSS, JS. Если с первыми двумя всё понятно, то про третий я совершенно не могу найти информацию. Есть целая куча готовых решений-библиотек, но как они работают? Понятно, что можно переключать классы, но я так подозреваю это не всё.

Куда идти? Что прочитать?

Comment: Читать и зубрить канвас.

Comment: @And Не понял. Между мной и svg лежит мост длинной в канвас или что?

Comment: Не обязательно, вы можете использовать `DOMParser` и написать свою библиотеку для работы с `SVG` полигонами и вершинами.

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex Поздравляю с перво тысячной репой!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Анимация - это движение, вот и подвигайте что-либо в svg в каждом кадре, в зависимости от времени:

```js
let PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
let bubbles = Array(33).fill(0).map((e, i) => { // создаем 33 частицы
    let d = Math.random() * PI2; // направление
    return {
        dir: d, // текущее направление
        targetDir: d, // целевое направление
        k: Math.random(), // коэфициент колебания частицы
        speed: 0.1 + Math.random(), // скорость
        size: Math.random() * 5 + 9, // размер частицы
        x: Math.random() * 560 - 280, // начальные координаты
        y: Math.random() * 170 - 85   // --
    };
});

// добавляем круги к svg по кол-ву частиц
background.innerHTML = bubbles.map((_, i) => `<circle></circle>`).join('');
let c = document.querySelectorAll('circle') // находим их все
requestAnimationFrame(render);

function render(t) {  // прорисовка кадра, тут t - время с начала анимации  
  requestAnimationFrame(render)
  
  bubbles.forEach((p, i) => { // для каждой частицы
  
     if (Math.random() > 0.995) // с очень небольшой вероятностью
       p.targetDir = Math.random() * PI2; // меняем направление движения
       
     let da = (p.targetDir - p.dir) % PI2; // считаем новое направление 
     p.dir += (2*da%PI2 - da)*0.1 + Math.sin(t/100+i)*0.05*p.k;// + колебания
     
     p.x += Math.cos(p.dir) * p.speed; // вычисляем новое положение
     p.y += Math.sin(p.dir) * p.speed; // с учетом скорости и направления
     
     if (Math.abs(p.x) > 300) p.x *= -1; // при выходе за границу 
     if (Math.abs(p.y) > 100) p.y *= -1; // переносим на противоположную сторону
     
     c[i].setAttribute('r', Math.max(0, p.size + 2*Math.sin(t/(444 + i*77))));
     c[i].setAttribute('cx', p.x);
     c[i].setAttribute('cy', p.y);
  });
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="-280 -85 560 170">
    <defs>
       <filter id="goo">
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" result="blur" />
          <feColorMatrix in="blur" values="
            1 0 0 0   0  
            0 1 0 0   0  
            0 0 1 0   0  
            0 0 0 17 -5"  />
       </filter>
    </defs>
    <g id=background filter=url(#goo) fill=white></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Пока это кажется чем то недостижимым...

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex написал комменты к коду

Comment: @Stranger in the Q а комменты к svg ? :))

Comment: @Leks а разве надо? :) Вопрос же про js, я плошагаю что svg уже слегка знаком..

Comment: @Stranger in the Q я конечно ни на что не намекаю, но может кто-то другой захочет прочитать значение svg свойств ...

Comment: @Leks рассказ про feColorMatrix может занять отдельную статью, а так там больше ничего и нет...

Comment: @Stranger in the Q ясно, спасибо, удачи ...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ что учить, что бы писать подобное `(2*da%PI2 - da)*0.1 + Math.sin(t/100+i)*0.05*p.k;`, да и вообще любые другие анимации не напрягаясь? Как это всё называется? Линейная алгебра? Я просто школу прогулял ((

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex это основы тригонометрии. не rocket science

Comment: @StrangerintheQ благодарствую

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex в целом - этим просто надо интересоваться и заниматься

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/KKwdoOP

Answer (score 7):

Допустим вы нашли или сами написали код анимации SVG и хотите полностью сделать точно такую же анимацию средствами JS

*Сравните два примера одной и той же анимации*

**SVG анимация увеличения радиуса окружности от `2 до 30px`**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">
 <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='20' fill="purple" id="crc1">
    <animate
      attributeName="r"
      from="2"
      to="30"
      dur="3s"
      repeatCount="2"
      fill="freeze" />
  </circle>
```

**JS анимация увеличения радиуса окружности от `2 до 30px`**

```js
var jsAnimation = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'animate');

jsAnimation.setAttribute('attributeName', 'r');
jsAnimation.setAttribute('from', '2');
jsAnimation.setAttribute('to', '30');
jsAnimation.setAttribute('dur', '3s');
jsAnimation.setAttribute('repeatCount', '2');
jsAnimation.setAttribute('fill', 'freeze');

document.getElementById('crc1').appendChild(jsAnimation);
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">
  <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='20' fill="purple" id="crc1">
  
  </circle>

</svg>
```

Пока практически всё одинаково.

Но у JS намного больше ресурсов сделать анимацию SVG более богатой, чем SMIL.

Например с использованием элементов управления HTML input, button, select и т.д

**Note**

*Но всегда нужно помнить, - чтобы заработала анимация JS, нужно полностью понимать как работает SVG.*

**Пример анимации заполнения полосы в зависимости от выбранного значения в `Input`**

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var anim = document.getElementById("anim");

slider.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {

  var sliderValue = evt.target.value;
  var currentTo = anim.getAttribute("to");
  anim.setAttribute("from", currentTo);
  anim.setAttribute("to", 400 - sliderValue);
  anim.beginElement();

});
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="400">
  <line x1="50" y1="400" x2="50" y2="0" stroke="lightgrey" stroke-width="20"/>
  <line x1="50" y1="400" x2="50" y2="400" stroke="red" stroke-width="20">
    <animate id="anim"
             attributeName="y2"
             to="400"
             dur="1s"
             fill="freeze"/>
  </line>
</svg>

<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="400" step="1" value="0"/>
```

**Пример использования триггера JS с переключением id анимаций SVG  `#open`, `#close`**

```js
var wrapper_svg_1 = document.getElementById("wrapper_svg_1"),
  close = document.getElementById('close'),
  open = document.getElementById("open");

let flag = true;

wrapper_svg_1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (flag == true) {
    close.beginElement();
    flag = false;
  } else {
    open.beginElement();
    flag = true;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #D74680;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <svg id="wrapper_svg_1" viewBox="0 0 301 301" width="301" height="301">
  
 <path fill="none" id="icon-active" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" d="M100 65, 160 5, 195 40, 135 100, 195 160, 160 195, 100 135, 40 195, 5 160,  65 100, 5 40, 40 5z">
 
  <animate id="close" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur="0.2s" 
     to="M5 5, 195 5, 195 195, 145 195, 145 40, 125 40, 125 195, 75 195, 75 40, 55 40, 55 195, 5 195z"></animate>
       <animate id="open" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur="0.2s" 
     to="M100 65, 160 5, 195 40, 135 100, 195 160, 160 195, 100 135, 40 195, 5 160,  65 100, 5 40, 40 5z"></animate>
</path>
 </svg>

</div>
```

Анимация запуска от кнопки - `GO` остановки - `Stop` с последующим запуском с того же места, где была остановлена анимация.

```js
 var SVGDocument = null;
  var SVGRoot = null;
  var pauseButton = null;
  var playButton = null;
  var innerCircle = null;
  var outerCircle = null;
  var smallerCircle = null;

  function Init(evt)
  {  
     SVGDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
     SVGRoot = SVGDocument.getElementById('SVGRoot')

     pauseButton = SVGDocument.getElementById('stop1');
     playButton = SVGDocument.getElementById('gO1');
     innerCircle = SVGDocument.getElementById('innerCircle');;
     outerCircle = SVGDocument.getElementById('outerCircle');;
     smallerCircle = SVGDocument.getElementById('smallerCircle');;
  };

  function Pause()
  {  
     SVGRoot.pauseAnimations();
  };

  function Play()
  {
     if(SVGRoot.animationsPaused()){
        SVGRoot.unpauseAnimations();
     }
     else{
         innerCircle.beginElement();
         outerCircle.beginElement();
         smallerCircle.beginElement();
     }
  };
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" onload='Init(evt)' id = "SVGRoot">
  <title>animation planetary mechanism</title>
  <defs>
    <marker id="MarkerArrow" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="2" refY="5" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
      <rect width="14" height="10" rx="2" fill="#22211D" />
    </marker>
    <line id="line1" x1="150" y1="100" x2="60" y2="100" style=" fill:none;
     marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow);
     marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow);
      stroke:#22211D; stroke-width:6; ">
    </line>
    <marker id="MarkerArrow-s" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="3" refY="1.7" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" orient="auto" markerWidth="20" markerHeight="20">
      <rect width="7" height="3.5" rx="2" fill="#22211D" />
    </marker>
    <line id="line-s" x1="175" y1="100" x2="202" y2="100" style=" fill:none;
    marker-end: url(#MarkerArrow-s1);
    marker-start: url(#MarkerArrow-s);
     stroke:#22211D; stroke-width:2; ">

    </line>
    <linearGradient id="vertical" x2="0%" y2="100%" spreadMethod="pad">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="powderblue" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="lightgreen" />
    </linearGradient>

  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#vertical)" />
  <g transform="translate(90,50)">

    <g id="wheel">
      <g>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 100 100" to="360 100 100" dur="14s" id = "innerCircle" begin="click" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <use xlink:href="#line1" transform="rotate(0 100 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line1" transform="rotate(120 100 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line1" transform="rotate(240 100 100)" />


        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="15" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 15px;" />
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="60" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 6;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />
      </g>
    </g>

    <g id="col-small">

      <g>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 188 100" to="-360 188 100" id = "smallerCircle" begin="click"  dur="3.5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(0 188 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(120 188 100)" />
        <use xlink:href="#line-s" transform="rotate(240 188 100)" />

        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="8" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 4px;" />
        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="18" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 7px;" />
        <circle cx="188" cy="100" r="24" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none; stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="206" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />

      </g>
    </g>
    
    <g id="planetar">
      <g>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 100 100" to="-360 100 100" id = "outerCircle" begin="click" dur="28s" repeatCount="indefinite" />

        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="116" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-dasharray: 5 5;  stroke-width: 10px;" />
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="124" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:none;   stroke-width: 12px;" />
        <circle cx="224" cy="100" r="3" style="stroke: #22211D; fill:yellow; " />
      </g>
    </g>

    <g>
      <use xlink:href="#col-small" transform="rotate(240 100 100)" />
      <use xlink:href="#col-small" transform="rotate(120 100 100)" />
    </g>

    <g transform="translate(-10,160)">
      <g id="gO1" onclick='Play()'>
        <rect x="45" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="#0080B8" stroke="dodgerblue" />
        <text x="62" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">GO</text>
      </g>
      <g id="stop1" onclick='Pause()'>
        <rect x="110" y="85" height="22" width="60" rx="5" fill="crimson" stroke="red" />
        <text x="120" y="102" font-size="16" fill="yellow">STOP</text>
      </g>
    </g>

  </g>
</svg>
```

**UPDATE**

Если возникнет необходимость сделать  морфинг с помощью JS и нескольких `path` SVG и анимация будет работать не плавно, рывками, то это значит:

> У двух или нескольких `path` SVG не  совпадают количество узлов, либо
>   команды `С`, `Q`, `T` кривых Безье не будут одинаковыми в одинаковых
>   по счёту узлах, либо path  имеют разрывы, либо контуры  не одинарные.

Как избежать этого и добиться плавной анимации морфинга подробно, с картинками :)написано здесь: [Плавный морфинг одного path в другой path](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1052883/28748)

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, в предпоследнем примере вы вручную задавали путь или с помощью редактора? Я так понял, что бы была возможность так плавно анимировать, нужно что бы количество команд было одинаковым и что бы они шли в одном и том же порядке, верно? Но, я, например, пробовал в фигме даже чуть чуть изменять какую то линию фигуры и путь уже отличался от первоначального(либо команды менялись местами, либо добавлялись новые). Так всегда происходит и нужно вручную все поправлять всегда, или я что то не то делаю?

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex как правило в редакторе делаю. Чтобы были все условия для плавного морфинга, выработал для себя определенную технику, последовательность шагов  [Плавный морфинг одного path в другой path](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1052883/28748)

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex Получилось сделать плавный морфинг? Если да, то интересно посмотреть ваш пример в дополнительном ответе Или здесь или в топике, где техника создания идентичных path описана. Я попробовал её ещё раз. Смотрите ответ 2

Comment: да, но это пока не кажется мне веселым занятием ) https://jsfiddle.net/5nj7ct31/

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex Но получилось же! А набьешь руку, будешь за 5 минут рисовать.  Анимация атрибута `d` в CSS к сожалению работает только в Chrome. В Firefox не работает, так как он более строго выполняет стандарты w3C

Answer (score 4):

### Морфинг и несколько вариантов запуска анимации с помощью JS

Для удобства приведу сначала вариант морфинга на `pure` SMIL, а затем несколько вариантов той же самой анимации с помощью JS

**SMIL, запуск анимации по клику на объекте**

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="260" viewBox="0 0 75 47">
  <path fill="#5F0C2D" stroke="#5F0C2D"  d="M0.4 5.9C0.4 6.3-0.3 17.8 4.3 31.2 5.3 32.4 6.1 37.9 7.5 43 10.4 53.6 10 58.2 10 58.2 10 58.2 10 59.1 10 62.2L10 63.4 15 65.7C20.1 67.8 34 67.6 38.6 65.7L44 64 44 62.2C44 60.3 44 61.2 44 59.6 44 59.6 44 58.2 44 58.2 44 58.2 44 56 44 56 44 56.1 44.2 52.2 44.2 52.2 44.2 52.2 44.5 49.3 44.5 49.3 44 47 46.8 39.1 47.6 38.8 48.4 38.6 52.8 37.6 55.4 37 62.3 36.7 68.5 30.5 68.5 26.9 68.5 25.1 68.5 20.3 66.1 17.8 63.5 14.8 60.4 14.1 56.7 14.2 54.2 14.3 54.2 12.8 54 12.6 53.8 12.5 54 12.6 54 10.8L53.3 6.7 51.3 4.6C49.8 3.6 47.5 3 44.7 2.2 38.3 0.5 20.1 0 12.7 1.4 7 2.4 0.4 4.7 0.4 5.9ZM64.8 22.9C64.8 25.9 65.5 27.9 60.6 31.8 59.6 32.6 64 30.3 62.9 30.8 60.9 31.9 53.6 32.7 52.4 31.8 51.6 31.1 51.1 29.8 51 28 51.3 24.6 52.1 22.1 53.6 20.4 57.4 16 64.8 19.2 64.8 22.9Z" fill-rule="nonzero" >
  <animate attributeName="d"
  begin="svg1.click"
  dur="3s"
  values="
  M0.4 5.9C0.4 6.3-0.3 17.8 4.3 31.2 5.3 32.4 6.1 37.9 7.5 43 10.4 53.6 10 58.2 10 58.2 10 58.2 10 59.1 10 62.2L10 63.4 15 65.7C20.1 67.8 34 67.6 38.6 65.7L44 64 44 62.2C44 60.3 44 61.2 44 59.6 44 59.6 44 58.2 44 58.2 44 58.2 44 56 44 56 44 56.1 44.2 52.2 44.2 52.2 44.2 52.2 44.5 49.3 44.5 49.3 44 47 46.8 39.1 47.6 38.8 48.4 38.6 52.8 37.6 55.4 37 62.3 36.7 68.5 30.5 68.5 26.9 68.5 25.1 68.5 20.3 66.1 17.8 63.5 14.8 60.4 14.1 56.7 14.2 54.2 14.3 54.2 12.8 54 12.6 53.8 12.5 54 12.6 54 10.8L53.3 6.7 51.3 4.6C49.8 3.6 47.5 3 44.7 2.2 38.3 0.5 20.1 0 12.7 1.4 7 2.4 0.4 4.7 0.4 5.9ZM64.8 22.9C64.8 25.9 65.5 27.9 60.6 31.8 59.6 32.6 64 30.3 62.9 30.8 60.9 31.9 53.6 32.7 52.4 31.8 51.6 31.1 51.1 29.8 51 28 51.3 24.6 52.1 22.1 53.6 20.4 57.4 16 64.8 19.2 64.8 22.9Z;
 
 M0 6.8C0 7.2 0.9 8.5 1.9 9.6 2.9 10.8 4.9 15.9 6.3 21 9.2 31.6 12.4 36.5 17.5 38.2 21.6 39.6 21.7 39.8 18.8 42.2L16.5 44 19.5 45.3C24.6 47.4 37 47.6 41.6 45.7L45.5 44.1 43.1 42.1C41 40.4 40.9 39.9 42.1 39.1 42.8 38.6 44.2 38.2 45.1 38.2 47 38.2 52.4 33.5 53.2 31.2 53.6 29.9 53.9 29.9 55.3 31 57.5 32.9 59.1 31.6 58.4 28.6 58 27 58.3 26.1 59.1 25.8 59.9 25.6 62.6 24.8 65.2 24.2 70.7 22.7 75 19 75 15.5 75 13.7 74.1 12.7 71.3 11.6 68 10.2 67.3 10.2 63.7 11.6 61.4 12.5 59.5 13 59.3 12.8 59.1 12.7 59.9 11.3 61 9.9L63.1 7.3 60.5 5.6C59 4.6 55.5 3.2 52.7 2.4 46.3 0.7 21.5-0.1 14.1 1.3 8.4 2.3 0 5.6 0 6.8ZM70 15.6C70 18.6 65.7 22.2 62.3 22.2 61 22.2 59 22.7 57.9 23.2 55.9 24.3 55.5 23.6 56.6 20.8 56.9 19.9 57.6 19.5 58.1 19.8 58.6 20.1 60.5 18.7 62.2 16.8 66 12.4 70 11.9 70 15.6Z"
  fill="freeze"
  restart="whenNotActive" />
 </path> 

</svg>
```

Как видите, сделать анимацию морфинга элемента SVG не трудно.

```
<animate attributeName="d" values="Начальный `path`; Финальный `path`" begin="svg1.click" dur="3s" />
```

Основная трудность выполнить требования идентичности по параметрам начального и финального `path`

**Запуск анимации JS по клику на объекте**

```
var animation = document.getElementById("morphing");
 document.querySelector('#svg1').addEventListener('click', e => {
  animation.beginElement();
 })
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="260" viewBox="0 0 75 47">
  <path fill="#5F0C2D" stroke="#5F0C2D"  d="M0.4 5.9C0.4 6.3-0.3 17.8 4.3 31.2 5.3 32.4 6.1 37.9 7.5 43 10.4 53.6 10 58.2 10 58.2 10 58.2 10 59.1 10 62.2L10 63.4 15 65.7C20.1 67.8 34 67.6 38.6 65.7L44 64 44 62.2C44 60.3 44 61.2 44 59.6 44 59.6 44 58.2 44 58.2 44 58.2 44 56 44 56 44 56.1 44.2 52.2 44.2 52.2 44.2 52.2 44.5 49.3 44.5 49.3 44 47 46.8 39.1 47.6 38.8 48.4 38.6 52.8 37.6 55.4 37 62.3 36.7 68.5 30.5 68.5 26.9 68.5 25.1 68.5 20.3 66.1 17.8 63.5 14.8 60.4 14.1 56.7 14.2 54.2 14.3 54.2 12.8 54 12.6 53.8 12.5 54 12.6 54 10.8L53.3 6.7 51.3 4.6C49.8 3.6 47.5 3 44.7 2.2 38.3 0.5 20.1 0 12.7 1.4 7 2.4 0.4 4.7 0.4 5.9ZM64.8 22.9C64.8 25.9 65.5 27.9 60.6 31.8 59.6 32.6 64 30.3 62.9 30.8 60.9 31.9 53.6 32.7 52.4 31.8 51.6 31.1 51.1 29.8 51 28 51.3 24.6 52.1 22.1 53.6 20.4 57.4 16 64.8 19.2 64.8 22.9Z" fill-rule="nonzero" >
  <animate id="morphing" attributeName="d"
  begin="indefinite"
  dur="4s"
  values="
  M0.4 5.9C0.4 6.3-0.3 17.8 4.3 31.2 5.3 32.4 6.1 37.9 7.5 43 10.4 53.6 10 58.2 10 58.2 10 58.2 10 59.1 10 62.2L10 63.4 15 65.7C20.1 67.8 34 67.6 38.6 65.7L44 64 44 62.2C44 60.3 44 61.2 44 59.6 44 59.6 44 58.2 44 58.2 44 58.2 44 56 44 56 44 56.1 44.2 52.2 44.2 52.2 44.2 52.2 44.5 49.3 44.5 49.3 44 47 46.8 39.1 47.6 38.8 48.4 38.6 52.8 37.6 55.4 37 62.3 36.7 68.5 30.5 68.5 26.9 68.5 25.1 68.5 20.3 66.1 17.8 63.5 14.8 60.4 14.1 56.7 14.2 54.2 14.3 54.2 12.8 54 12.6 53.8 12.5 54 12.6 54 10.8L53.3 6.7 51.3 4.6C49.8 3.6 47.5 3 44.7 2.2 38.3 0.5 20.1 0 12.7 1.4 7 2.4 0.4 4.7 0.4 5.9ZM64.8 22.9C64.8 25.9 65.5 27.9 60.6 31.8 59.6 32.6 64 30.3 62.9 30.8 60.9 31.9 53.6 32.7 52.4 31.8 51.6 31.1 51.1 29.8 51 28 51.3 24.6 52.1 22.1 53.6 20.4 57.4 16 64.8 19.2 64.8 22.9Z;
 
 M0 6.8C0 7.2 0.9 8.5 1.9 9.6 2.9 10.8 4.9 15.9 6.3 21 9.2 31.6 12.4 36.5 17.5 38.2 21.6 39.6 21.7 39.8 18.8 42.2L16.5 44 19.5 45.3C24.6 47.4 37 47.6 41.6 45.7L45.5 44.1 43.1 42.1C41 40.4 40.9 39.9 42.1 39.1 42.8 38.6 44.2 38.2 45.1 38.2 47 38.2 52.4 33.5 53.2 31.2 53.6 29.9 53.9 29.9 55.3 31 57.5 32.9 59.1 31.6 58.4 28.6 58 27 58.3 26.1 59.1 25.8 59.9 25.6 62.6 24.8 65.2 24.2 70.7 22.7 75 19 75 15.5 75 13.7 74.1 12.7 71.3 11.6 68 10.2 67.3 10.2 63.7 11.6 61.4 12.5 59.5 13 59.3 12.8 59.1 12.7 59.9 11.3 61 9.9L63.1 7.3 60.5 5.6C59 4.6 55.5 3.2 52.7 2.4 46.3 0.7 21.5-0.1 14.1 1.3 8.4 2.3 0 5.6 0 6.8ZM70 15.6C70 18.6 65.7 22.2 62.3 22.2 61 22.2 59 22.7 57.9 23.2 55.9 24.3 55.5 23.6 56.6 20.8 56.9 19.9 57.6 19.5 58.1 19.8 58.6 20.1 60.5 18.7 62.2 16.8 66 12.4 70 11.9 70 15.6Z
  "
  fill="freeze"
  restart="whenNotActive" />
 </path> 
 </svg>

<script>            
 var animation = document.getElementById("morphing");
 document.querySelector('#svg1').addEventListener('click', e => {
  animation.beginElement();
 })
 </script>
```

**Запуск анимации JS по клику на кнопке**

```
<button id ="button" onclick="showSVG()">Morphing</button>
```

```
var animation = document.getElementById("morphing")
function showSVG(){
     animation.beginElement();
}
```

```html
<button id ="button" onclick="showSVG()">Morphing</button> 

<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="260" viewBox="0 0 75 47">
  <path fill="#5F0C2D" stroke="#5F0C2D"  d="M0.4 5.9C0.4 6.3-0.3 17.8 4.3 31.2 5.3 32.4 6.1 37.9 7.5 43 10.4 53.6 10 58.2 10 58.2 10 58.2 10 59.1 10 62.2L10 63.4 15 65.7C20.1 67.8 34 67.6 38.6 65.7L44 64 44 62.2C44 60.3 44 61.2 44 59.6 44 59.6 44 58.2 44 58.2 44 58.2 44 56 44 56 44 56.1 44.2 52.2 44.2 52.2 44.2 52.2 44.5 49.3 44.5 49.3 44 47 46.8 39.1 47.6 38.8 48.4 38.6 52.8 37.6 55.4 37 62.3 36.7 68.5 30.5 68.5 26.9 68.5 25.1 68.5 20.3 66.1 17.8 63.5 14.8 60.4 14.1 56.7 14.2 54.2 14.3 54.2 12.8 54 12.6 53.8 12.5 54 12.6 54 10.8L53.3 6.7 51.3 4.6C49.8 3.6 47.5 3 44.7 2.2 38.3 0.5 20.1 0 12.7 1.4 7 2.4 0.4 4.7 0.4 5.9ZM64.8 22.9C64.8 25.9 65.5 27.9 60.6 31.8 59.6 32.6 64 30.3 62.9 30.8 60.9 31.9 53.6 32.7 52.4 31.8 51.6 31.1 51.1 29.8 51 28 51.3 24.6 52.1 22.1 53.6 20.4 57.4 16 64.8 19.2 64.8 22.9Z" fill-rule="nonzero" >
  <animate id="morphing" attributeName="d"
  begin="indefinite"
  dur="4s"
  values="
  M0.4 5.9C0.4 6.3-0.3 17.8 4.3 31.2 5.3 32.4 6.1 37.9 7.5 43 10.4 53.6 10 58.2 10 58.2 10 58.2 10 59.1 10 62.2L10 63.4 15 65.7C20.1 67.8 34 67.6 38.6 65.7L44 64 44 62.2C44 60.3 44 61.2 44 59.6 44 59.6 44 58.2 44 58.2 44 58.2 44 56 44 56 44 56.1 44.2 52.2 44.2 52.2 44.2 52.2 44.5 49.3 44.5 49.3 44 47 46.8 39.1 47.6 38.8 48.4 38.6 52.8 37.6 55.4 37 62.3 36.7 68.5 30.5 68.5 26.9 68.5 25.1 68.5 20.3 66.1 17.8 63.5 14.8 60.4 14.1 56.7 14.2 54.2 14.3 54.2 12.8 54 12.6 53.8 12.5 54 12.6 54 10.8L53.3 6.7 51.3 4.6C49.8 3.6 47.5 3 44.7 2.2 38.3 0.5 20.1 0 12.7 1.4 7 2.4 0.4 4.7 0.4 5.9ZM64.8 22.9C64.8 25.9 65.5 27.9 60.6 31.8 59.6 32.6 64 30.3 62.9 30.8 60.9 31.9 53.6 32.7 52.4 31.8 51.6 31.1 51.1 29.8 51 28 51.3 24.6 52.1 22.1 53.6 20.4 57.4 16 64.8 19.2 64.8 22.9Z;
 
 M0 6.8C0 7.2 0.9 8.5 1.9 9.6 2.9 10.8 4.9 15.9 6.3 21 9.2 31.6 12.4 36.5 17.5 38.2 21.6 39.6 21.7 39.8 18.8 42.2L16.5 44 19.5 45.3C24.6 47.4 37 47.6 41.6 45.7L45.5 44.1 43.1 42.1C41 40.4 40.9 39.9 42.1 39.1 42.8 38.6 44.2 38.2 45.1 38.2 47 38.2 52.4 33.5 53.2 31.2 53.6 29.9 53.9 29.9 55.3 31 57.5 32.9 59.1 31.6 58.4 28.6 58 27 58.3 26.1 59.1 25.8 59.9 25.6 62.6 24.8 65.2 24.2 70.7 22.7 75 19 75 15.5 75 13.7 74.1 12.7 71.3 11.6 68 10.2 67.3 10.2 63.7 11.6 61.4 12.5 59.5 13 59.3 12.8 59.1 12.7 59.9 11.3 61 9.9L63.1 7.3 60.5 5.6C59 4.6 55.5 3.2 52.7 2.4 46.3 0.7 21.5-0.1 14.1 1.3 8.4 2.3 0 5.6 0 6.8ZM70 15.6C70 18.6 65.7 22.2 62.3 22.2 61 22.2 59 22.7 57.9 23.2 55.9 24.3 55.5 23.6 56.6 20.8 56.9 19.9 57.6 19.5 58.1 19.8 58.6 20.1 60.5 18.7 62.2 16.8 66 12.4 70 11.9 70 15.6Z
  "
  fill="freeze"
  restart="whenNotActive" />
 </path>
</svg> 

 <script>
var animation = document.getElementById("morphing")
function showSVG(){
     animation.beginElement();
}
</script>
```

**Анимация с помощью библиотеки SnapJS**

```
var svg = document.getElementById("svg1");
var s = Snap(svg);

var simpleCup = Snap.select('#coffee-cup');
var fancyCup = Snap.select('#fancy-cup');

var simpleCupPoints = simpleCup.node.getAttribute('d');
var fancyCupPoints = fancyCup.node.getAttribute('d');


var toFancy = function(){
  simpleCup.animate({ d: fancyCupPoints }, 1000, mina.backout, toSimple);  
}

var toSimple = function(){
  simpleCup.animate({ d: simpleCupPoints }, 1000, mina.backout, toFancy); 
}


toSimple();
```

```html
<h1 style="color:#5F0C2D">Наслаждайтесь своим кофе с SVG +snap.js;) </h1>
  <svg id="svg1" width="100" height="130" viewBox="0 0 75 47" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path id="coffee-cup" fill="#5F0C2D" stroke="#5F0C2D"  d="M0.4 5.9C0.4 6.3-0.3 17.8 4.3 31.2 5.3 32.4 6.1 37.9 7.5 43 10.4 53.6 10 58.2 10 58.2 10 58.2 10 59.1 10 62.2L10 63.4 15 65.7C20.1 67.8 34 67.6 38.6 65.7L44 64 44 62.2C44 60.3 44 61.2 44 59.6 44 59.6 44 58.2 44 58.2 44 58.2 44 56 44 56 44 56.1 44.2 52.2 44.2 52.2 44.2 52.2 44.5 49.3 44.5 49.3 44 47 46.8 39.1 47.6 38.8 48.4 38.6 52.8 37.6 55.4 37 62.3 36.7 68.5 30.5 68.5 26.9 68.5 25.1 68.5 20.3 66.1 17.8 63.5 14.8 60.4 14.1 56.7 14.2 54.2 14.3 54.2 12.8 54 12.6 53.8 12.5 54 12.6 54 10.8L53.3 6.7 51.3 4.6C49.8 3.6 47.5 3 44.7 2.2 38.3 0.5 20.1 0 12.7 1.4 7 2.4 0.4 4.7 0.4 5.9ZM64.8 22.9C64.8 25.9 65.5 27.9 60.6 31.8 59.6 32.6 64 30.3 62.9 30.8 60.9 31.9 53.6 32.7 52.4 31.8 51.6 31.1 51.1 29.8 51 28 51.3 24.6 52.1 22.1 53.6 20.4 57.4 16 64.8 19.2 64.8 22.9Z"  />
    <path opacity="0"  id="fancy-cup" fill="#5F0C2D" stroke="#5F0C2D"  d="M0 6.8C0 7.2 0.9 8.5 1.9 9.6 2.9 10.8 4.9 15.9 6.3 21 9.2 31.6 12.4 36.5 17.5 38.2 21.6 39.6 21.7 39.8 18.8 42.2L16.5 44 19.5 45.3C24.6 47.4 37 47.6 41.6 45.7L45.5 44.1 43.1 42.1C41 40.4 40.9 39.9 42.1 39.1 42.8 38.6 44.2 38.2 45.1 38.2 47 38.2 52.4 33.5 53.2 31.2 53.6 29.9 53.9 29.9 55.3 31 57.5 32.9 59.1 31.6 58.4 28.6 58 27 58.3 26.1 59.1 25.8 59.9 25.6 62.6 24.8 65.2 24.2 70.7 22.7 75 19 75 15.5 75 13.7 74.1 12.7 71.3 11.6 68 10.2 67.3 10.2 63.7 11.6 61.4 12.5 59.5 13 59.3 12.8 59.1 12.7 59.9 11.3 61 9.9L63.1 7.3 60.5 5.6C59 4.6 55.5 3.2 52.7 2.4 46.3 0.7 21.5-0.1 14.1 1.3 8.4 2.3 0 5.6 0 6.8ZM70 15.6C70 18.6 65.7 22.2 62.3 22.2 61 22.2 59 22.7 57.9 23.2 55.9 24.3 55.5 23.6 56.6 20.8 56.9 19.9 57.6 19.5 58.1 19.8 58.6 20.1 60.5 18.7 62.2 16.8 66 12.4 70 11.9 70 15.6Z"  />

</svg>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
  
  <script> 
var svg = document.getElementById("svg1");
var s = Snap(svg);

var simpleCup = Snap.select('#coffee-cup');
var fancyCup = Snap.select('#fancy-cup');

var simpleCupPoints = simpleCup.node.getAttribute('d');
var fancyCupPoints = fancyCup.node.getAttribute('d');


var toFancy = function(){
  simpleCup.animate({ d: fancyCupPoints }, 1000, mina.backout, toSimple);  
}

var toSimple = function(){
  simpleCup.animate({ d: simpleCupPoints }, 1000, mina.backout, toFancy); 
}


toSimple();
  </script>
```