# Почему мой код создания морфов работает не стабильно?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Я создал вот такой код для деформаций SVG файлов

html

```
<div id="svg_opt"></div>

<div class="frame_1">
 <svg width="580" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 621.69 605.5"><defs><style>.patch1{fill:#ff0;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}</style></defs><title>1</title>
   <path class="patch1" d="M1037.5,403.5C958.4300000000001,388.64,705.5,366.5,705.5,366.5L670.5,7.5L654.5,365.5L302.5,393.5L653.71,409.33L682.5,751.5L702.5,408.29Z" transform="translate(-365.81 -73.5)"/></svg>
</div>
```

js

```
//------------------TO_POINT------------------


const toPoints = ({ type, ...props }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'circle':
      return getPointsFromCircle(props)
    case 'ellipse':
      return getPointsFromEllipse(props)
    case 'line':
      return getPointsFromLine(props)
    case 'path':
      return getPointsFromPath(props)
    case 'polygon':
      return getPointsFromPolygon(props)
    case 'polyline':
      return getPointsFromPolyline(props)
    case 'rect':
      return getPointsFromRect(props)
    case 'g':
      return getPointsFromG(props)
    default:
      throw new Error('Not a valid shape type')
  }
}

const getPointsFromCircle = ({ cx, cy, r }) => {
  return [
    { x: cx, y: cy - r, moveTo: true },
    { x: cx, y: cy + r, curve: { type: 'arc', rx: r, ry: r, sweepFlag: 1 } },
    { x: cx, y: cy - r, curve: { type: 'arc', rx: r, ry: r, sweepFlag: 1 } }
  ]
}

const getPointsFromEllipse = ({ cx, cy, rx, ry }) => {
  return [
    { x: cx, y: cy - ry, moveTo: true },
    { x: cx, y: cy + ry, curve: { type: 'arc', rx, ry, sweepFlag: 1 } },
    { x: cx, y: cy - ry, curve: { type: 'arc', rx, ry, sweepFlag: 1 } }
  ]
}

const getPointsFromLine = ({ x1, x2, y1, y2 }) => {
  return [
    { x: x1, y: y1, moveTo: true },
    { x: x2, y: y2 }
  ]
}

const validCommands = /[MmLlHhVvCcSsQqTtAaZz]/g

const commandLengths = {
  A: 7,
  C: 6,
  H: 1,
  L: 2,
  M: 2,
  Q: 4,
  S: 4,
  T: 2,
  V: 1,
  Z: 0
}

const relativeCommands = [
  'a',
  'c',
  'h',
  'l',
  'm',
  'q',
  's',
  't',
  'v'
]

const isRelative = command => relativeCommands.indexOf(command) !== -1

const optionalArcKeys = [ 'xAxisRotation', 'largeArcFlag', 'sweepFlag' ]

const getCommands = d => d.match(validCommands)

const getParams = d => d.split(validCommands)
  .map(v => v.replace(/[0-9]+-/g, m => `${m.slice(0, -1)} -`))
  .map(v => v.replace(/\.[0-9]+/g, m => `${m} `))
  .map(v => v.trim())
  .filter(v => v.length > 0)
  .map(v => v.split(/[ ,]+/)
    .map(parseFloat)
    .filter(n => !isNaN(n))
  )

const getPointsFromPath = ({ d }) => {
  const commands = getCommands(d)
  const params = getParams(d)

  const points = []

  let moveTo

  for (let i = 0, l = commands.length; i < l; i++) {
    const command = commands[ i ]
    const upperCaseCommand = command.toUpperCase()
    const commandLength = commandLengths[ upperCaseCommand ]
    const relative = isRelative(command)

    if (commandLength > 0) {
      const commandParams = params.shift()
      const iterations = commandParams.length / commandLength

      for (let j = 0; j < iterations; j++) {
        const prevPoint = points[ points.length - 1 ] || { x: 0, y: 0 }

        switch (upperCaseCommand) {
          case 'M':
            const x = (relative ? prevPoint.x : 0) + commandParams.shift()
            const y = (relative ? prevPoint.y : 0) + commandParams.shift()

            if (j === 0) {
              moveTo = { x, y }
              points.push({ x, y, moveTo: true })
            } else {
              points.push({ x, y })
            }

            break

          case 'L':
            points.push({
              x: (relative ? prevPoint.x : 0) + commandParams.shift(),
              y: (relative ? prevPoint.y : 0) + commandParams.shift()
            })

            break

          case 'H':
            points.push({
              x: (relative ? prevPoint.x : 0) + commandParams.shift(),
              y: prevPoint.y
            })

            break

          case 'V':
            points.push({
              x: prevPoint.x,
              y: (relative ? prevPoint.y : 0) + commandParams.shift()
            })

            break

          case 'A':
            points.push({
              curve: {
                type: 'arc',
                rx: commandParams.shift(),
                ry: commandParams.shift(),
                xAxisRotation: commandParams.shift(),
                largeArcFlag: commandParams.shift(),
                sweepFlag: commandParams.shift()
              },
              x: (relative ? prevPoint.x : 0) + commandParams.shift(),
              y: (relative ? prevPoint.y : 0) + commandParams.shift()
            })

            for (let k of optionalArcKeys) {
              if (points[ points.length - 1 ][ 'curve' ][ k ] === 0) {
                delete points[ points.length - 1 ][ 'curve' ][ k ]
              }
            }

            break

          case 'C':
            points.push({
              curve: {
                type: 'cubic',
                x1: (relative ? prevPoint.x : 0) + commandParams.shift(),
                y1: (relative ? prevPoint.y : 0) + commandParams.shift(),
                x2: (relative ? prevPoint.x : 0) + commandParams.shift(),
                y2: (relative ? prevPoint.y : 0) + commandParams.shift()
              },
              x: (relative ? prevPoint.x : 0) + commandParams.shift(),
              y: (relative ? prevPoint.y : 0) + commandParams.shift()
            })

            break

          case 'S':
            const sx2 = (relative ? prevPoint.x : 0) + commandParams.shift()
            const sy2 = (relative ? prevPoint.y : 0) + commandParams.shift()
            const sx = (relative ? prevPoint.x : 0) + commandParams.shift()
            const sy = (relative ? prevPoint.y : 0) + commandParams.shift()

            const diff = {}

            let sx1
            let sy1

            if (prevPoint.curve && prevPoint.curve.type === 'cubic') {
              diff.x = Math.abs(prevPoint.x - prevPoint.curve.x2)
              diff.y = Math.abs(prevPoint.y - prevPoint.curve.y2)
              sx1 = prevPoint.x < prevPoint.curve.x2 ? prevPoint.x - diff.x : prevPoint.x + diff.x
              sy1 = prevPoint.y < prevPoint.curve.y2 ? prevPoint.y - diff.y : prevPoint.y + diff.y
            } else {
              diff.x = Math.abs(sx - sx2)
              diff.y = Math.abs(sy - sy2)
              sx1 = prevPoint.x
              sy1 = prevPoint.y
            }

            points.push({ curve: { type: 'cubic', x1: sx1, y1: sy1, x2: sx2, y2: sy2 }, x: sx, y: sy })

            break

          case 'Q':
            points.push({
              curve: {
                type: 'quadratic',
                x1: (relative ? prevPoint.x : 0) + commandParams.shift(),
                y1: (relative ? prevPoint.y : 0) + commandParams.shift()
              },
              x: (relative ? prevPoint.x : 0) + commandParams.shift(),
              y: (relative ? prevPoint.y : 0) + commandParams.shift()
            })

            break

          case 'T':
            const tx = (relative ? prevPoint.x : 0) + commandParams.shift()
            const ty = (relative ? prevPoint.y : 0) + commandParams.shift()

            let tx1
            let ty1

            if (prevPoint.curve && prevPoint.curve.type === 'quadratic') {
              const diff = {
                x: Math.abs(prevPoint.x - prevPoint.curve.x1),
                y: Math.abs(prevPoint.y - prevPoint.curve.y1)
              }

              tx1 = prevPoint.x < prevPoint.curve.x1 ? prevPoint.x - diff.x : prevPoint.x + diff.x
              ty1 = prevPoint.y < prevPoint.curve.y1 ? prevPoint.y - diff.y : prevPoint.y + diff.y
            } else {
              tx1 = prevPoint.x
              ty1 = prevPoint.y
            }

            points.push({ curve: { type: 'quadratic', x1: tx1, y1: ty1 }, x: tx, y: ty })

            break
        }
      }
    } else {
      const prevPoint = points[ points.length - 1 ] || { x: 0, y: 0 }

      if (prevPoint.x !== moveTo.x || prevPoint.y !== moveTo.y) {
        points.push({ x: moveTo.x, y: moveTo.y })
      }
    }
  }

  return points
}

const getPointsFromPolygon = ({ points }) => {
  return getPointsFromPoints({ closed: true, points })
}

const getPointsFromPolyline = ({ points }) => {
  return getPointsFromPoints({ closed: false, points })
}

const getPointsFromPoints = ({ closed, points }) => {
  const numbers = points.split(/[\s,]+/).map(n => parseFloat(n))

  const p = numbers.reduce((arr, point, i) => {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      arr.push({ x: point })
    } else {
      arr[ (i - 1) / 2 ].y = point
    }

    return arr
  }, [])

  if (closed) {
    p.push({ ...p[ 0 ] })
  }

  p[ 0 ].moveTo = true

  return p
}

const getPointsFromRect = ({ height, rx, ry, width, x, y }) => {
  if (rx || ry) {
    return getPointsFromRectWithCornerRadius({
      height,
      rx: rx || ry,
      ry: ry || rx,
      width,
      x,
      y
    })
  }

  return getPointsFromBasicRect({ height, width, x, y })
}

const getPointsFromBasicRect = ({ height, width, x, y }) => {
  return [
    { x, y, moveTo: true },
    { x: x + width, y },
    { x: x + width, y: y + height },
    { x, y: y + height },
    { x, y }
  ]
}

const getPointsFromRectWithCornerRadius = ({ height, rx, ry, width, x, y }) => {
  const curve = { type: 'arc', rx, ry, sweepFlag: 1 }

  return [
    { x: x + rx, y, moveTo: true },
    { x: x + width - rx, y },
    { x: x + width, y: y + ry, curve },
    { x: x + width, y: y + height - ry },
    { x: x + width - rx, y: y + height, curve },
    { x: x + rx, y: y + height },
    { x, y: y + height - ry, curve },
    { x, y: y + ry },
    { x: x + rx, y, curve }
  ]
}

const getPointsFromG = ({ shapes }) => shapes.map(s => toPoints(s))


const pointsToD = p => {
  let d = ''
  let i = 0
  let firstPoint

  for (let point of p) {
    const { curve = false, moveTo, x, y } = point
    const isFirstPoint = i === 0 || moveTo
    const isLastPoint = i === p.length - 1 || p[ i + 1 ].moveTo
    const prevPoint = i === 0 ? null : p[ i - 1 ]

    if (isFirstPoint) {
      firstPoint = point

      if (!isLastPoint) {
        d += `M${x},${y}`
      }
    } else if (curve) {
      switch (curve.type) {
        case 'arc':
          const { largeArcFlag = 0, rx, ry, sweepFlag = 0, xAxisRotation = 0 } = point.curve
          d += `A${rx},${ry},${xAxisRotation},${largeArcFlag},${sweepFlag},${x},${y}`
          break
        case 'cubic':
          const { x1: cx1, y1: cy1, x2: cx2, y2: cy2 } = point.curve
          d += `C${cx1},${cy1},${cx2},${cy2},${x},${y}`
          break
        case 'quadratic':
          const { x1: qx1, y1: qy1 } = point.curve
          d += `Q${qx1},${qy1},${x},${y}`
          break
      }

      if (isLastPoint && x === firstPoint.x && y === firstPoint.y) {
        d += 'Z'
      }
    } else if (isLastPoint && x === firstPoint.x && y === firstPoint.y) {
      d += 'Z'
    } else if (x !== prevPoint.x && y !== prevPoint.y) {
      d += `L${x},${y}`
    } else if (x !== prevPoint.x) {
      d += `H${x}`
    } else if (y !== prevPoint.y) {
      d += `V${y}`
    }

    i++
  }

  return d
}

//------------------TO_POINT------------------

//------------------TO_PATCH------------------

const toPath = s => {
  const isPoints = Array.isArray(s)
  const isGroup = isPoints ? (Array.isArray(s[ 0 ])) : (s.type === 'g')
  const points = isPoints ? s : (isGroup ? s.shapes.map(shp => toPoints(shp)) : toPoints(s))

  if (isGroup) {
    return points.map(p => pointsToD(p))
  }

  return pointsToD(points)
}

//------------------TO_PATCH------------------

//------------------READ_COOKIE------------------

function readCookie(name) {var name_cook = name+"=";var spl = document.cookie.split(";");for(var i=0; i<spl.length; i++) {var c = spl[i];while(c.charAt(0) == " ") {c = c.substring(1, c.length);}if(c.indexOf(name_cook)==0){return c.substring(name_cook.length, c.length);}}return null;}

//------------------READ_COOKIE------------------





function get_path(d){
    return $(d).attr('d');
};

//Общая функция
function conect_morh(name_svg){
//Массив всех морфов
morh_arr_name =
{
  "start": $(name_svg).attr('d'),
  "path2": "M366.5,74.5c43,68,289,295,289,295l-289.19,309,317.19-279L987,678.5l-270.5-308L987,74,682.5,335.5Z",
  "path3": "M148.802,244.876c2.737-36.735,16.107-69.079,40.099-97.061c27.038-31.596,60.924-47.386,101.629-47.386c15.481,0,38.483,2.447,69.024,7.287c30.541,4.886,53.533,7.278,69.033,7.278c23.693,0,57.868,8.847,102.526,26.477c7.914,3.009,17.471,11.239,28.701,24.59c6.381,7.886,16.256,19.769,29.616,35.568c3.036,2.139,6.998,5.316,11.865,9.595c4.859,4.223,8.194,6.063,9.997,5.456c0.616-1.84,2.149-4.4,4.578-7.735c1.214-1.225,1.962-1.832,2.261-1.832c0.935,0.607,1.831,1.215,2.747,1.832c0.906,0.616,1.205,2.419,0.906,5.456c-0.616,5.474-0.906,7.138-0.906,4.998c-0.327,3.056-0.757,5.008-1.373,5.952c-3.952,6.671-5.485,11.847-4.55,15.472c0.916,3.325,3.765,8.669,8.642,15.958c4.868,7.287,7.586,12.761,8.193,16.405c-0.299,2.728-0.43,7.119-0.43,13.211l-4.568,11.379c0,8.512,9.865,23.114,29.616,43.78c9.436,4.223,14.117,18.826,14.117,43.714c0,19.47-16.089,29.167-48.273,29.167c-4.26,0-8.81-0.13-13.678-0.467c-3.335-1.196-8.203-2.56-14.575-4.074c-7.586-0.934-12.761-3.494-15.48-7.773c-4.877-6.95-12.781-13.509-23.711-19.581c-1.823-0.878-4.485-4.223-7.979-10.016c-3.503-5.774-6.615-9.418-9.333-10.949c-2.719-1.495-6.68-1.813-11.856-0.878c-8.81,1.494-13.677,2.261-14.574,2.261c-2.139,0-5.25-0.598-9.343-1.831c-4.11-1.215-7.054-1.831-8.893-1.831c-2.112,9.735-2.589,19.152-1.364,28.252c0.298,2.448,1.831,4.428,4.559,5.923c4.27,3.046,6.531,4.709,6.849,5.045c2.718,2.111,5.615,5.605,8.642,10.445c0.616,1.849-0.523,4.952-3.419,9.342c-2.887,4.41-5.223,7.008-7.063,7.736c-1.813,0.785-5.765,1.178-11.847,1.178c-8.82,0-12.295,0.131-10.464,0.43c-12.145-1.831-18.984-2.878-20.516-3.158c-7.587-1.532-14.126-3.943-19.582-7.305c-2.756-1.813-5.913-10.333-9.557-25.524c-3.681-16.406-6.717-26.272-9.137-29.635c-0.598-0.896-1.355-1.326-2.261-1.326c-1.533,0-4.045,1.494-7.53,4.559c-3.494,2.99-5.858,4.652-7.054,5.008c-4.242,17.9-6.4,26.402-6.4,25.468c0,7.007,1.972,12.892,5.924,17.77c3.943,4.858,8.063,9.567,12.323,14.107c5.157,5.774,7.736,10.782,7.736,15.042c0,2.41-0.748,4.521-2.28,6.372c-6.381,7.885-17.022,11.847-31.905,11.847c-16.713,0-27.644-2.28-32.792-6.839c-6.699-5.774-10.949-11.865-12.762-18.199c-0.298-1.533-1.055-6.091-2.28-13.678c-0.607-4.578-1.98-7.287-4.082-8.184c-6.101-0.916-13.687-2.578-22.778-5.007c-1.841-1.215-3.811-4.26-5.942-9.118c-3.933-9.399-6.83-15.789-8.661-19.134c-9.128-4.56-23.702-9.698-43.761-15.453c-0.916,1.831-1.345,4.373-1.345,7.718c3.335,4.26,8.343,10.8,15.032,19.581c5.466,7.288,8.203,14.295,8.203,20.965c0,12.781-8.203,19.134-24.609,19.134c-12.453,0-20.955-0.878-25.523-2.709c-6.671-2.728-12.295-9.136-16.854-19.134c-7.596-16.742-11.847-26.159-12.762-28.27c-4.868-11.231-8.204-21.133-10.006-29.653c-1.233-6.055-3.064-15.35-5.485-27.804c-2.121-10.296-5.456-18.358-10.015-24.132C155.332,279.36,147.578,260.665,148.802,244.876z"
};




//Перебор масива
$.each(morh_arr_name, function(key, value ) {
if (key != 'start'){

//Создать ползунок контроля морфа
str_name = "s_opt_";
ran_id = str_name+"run_"+key;
box_id = str_name+"box_"+key;
$("#svg_opt").append('<div class ="'+str_name+'_block" id="'+str_name+'_block_'+key+'"><label>'+key+'</label><input type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0" class="'+key+'" id="'+ran_id+'"><input type="checkbox" name="'+box_id+'" id="'+box_id+'" ></div>');
//Запуск ползунка
$("#"+ran_id).change(function() {


//Получить id чекбокса
var box_id = str_name+"box_"+$(this).attr('class');
//Получить сроку svg
now_pach = $(name_svg).attr('d');
//Узнать уменьшается или увеличивается значение
var num_step =  Number(readCookie($(this).attr('class'))); 
//Условие одинаковости










 //Ползунок
var ran_start = num_step; // 2
var ran_end = $(this).attr('max');  // 10  
var ran_now = $(this).val(); // 3




//Функций пересчета пути
function morh_up_str(start, now, end){
var run_step = (end - start) / (ran_end - ran_start);      
var new_val = start+run_step*(ran_now-ran_start); 

return  new_val
}
function morh_dw_str(start, now, end){
var run_step = (now-start)/ran_start; 
var new_val = now-run_step*(ran_start-ran_now); 

return  new_val
}
function morh_up_inc(start, now, end){
var run_step = (end-start)/ran_end; //1  
var new_val = now+run_step*(ran_now-ran_start);  
return new_val;
}
function morh_dw_inc(start, now, end){
var run_step = (end-start)/ran_end; //1 
var new_val = now-run_step*(ran_start-ran_now);  
return new_val;
}




//Получить массив точек текущего файла
var arr_now_point = toPoints({type: 'path', d: now_pach});
//Получить массив точек морфа
var arr_point_end = toPoints({type: 'path', d: value});
//Получить массив точек начального морфа
var arr_point_start = toPoints({type: 'path', d: morh_arr_name["start"]});




if(JSON.stringify(arr_point_start)==JSON.stringify(arr_now_point)) {
  num_step = 0;
}





//проверить количество элементов
if(arr_point_end.length != arr_now_point.length){
console.log('%c[WARNING]', 'color: white; background: yellow;', 'arr_point_end = '+ arr_point_end.length + 'arr_now_point = ' + arr_now_point.length);
}
//Создать результат массива
var result = [];
//Какую функцию запускать?
 var func;
//Ползунок поднимается или опускается?
if (num_step < ran_now){ 
// проверить включен ли чекбокс
console.log('up');
if($("#"+box_id).prop("checked") == true ){
func = morh_up_str;
console.log('on');
} else {
func = morh_up_inc;
console.log('off');
}
//Обновить куки 
$("#"+str_name+'_block_'+$(this).attr('class')).css({'background':'green'});
document.cookie = encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('class')) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(ran_now);
}
else if (num_step > ran_now){
console.log('down');
// проверить включен ли чекбокс
if($("#"+box_id).prop("checked") == true ){
func = morh_dw_str;
console.log('on');
} else {
func = morh_dw_inc;
console.log('off');
}
//Обновить куки 
$("#"+str_name+'_block_'+$(this).attr('class')).css({'background':'blue'});
document.cookie = encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('class')) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(ran_now);
}

now_test = [{x: 10, y: 10}];
star_test = [{x: 10, y: 10}];
end_test = [{x: 20, y: 20}];

//Запуск подсчета
for(let idx = 0; idx < arr_now_point.length; idx++){
    const a = arr_point_start[idx],
          b = arr_now_point[idx],
          c = arr_point_end[idx]; 

    const curve = a.curve || b.curve || c.curve;         

    var item =  { };

    if(curve){
        const points = ['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2'];
        item.curve = { type: 'cubic' };

        let cp = (v,p) => v.curve ? v.curve[p] : 0;

        points.forEach(function(p){
            item.curve[p] = func(cp(a,p), cp(b,p), cp(c,p));
        });    
    }

    if(a.moveTo){
    item.moveTo = a.moveTo;
    }

    item.x = func(a.x, b.x, c.x);
    item.y = func(a.y, b.y, c.y);

    result.push(item);
}   

$(name_svg).attr('d',toPath(result)) ;

});


$("#"+box_id).change(function() {
alert(this.checked);
});


}

});


}

conect_morh('.patch1')
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/zeni-agentt/pen/yLNggZQ)

Для работы я взял код из JQuery, toPoints, toPath, readCookie.
Но он у меня работает очень не стабильно и криво,
то морф деформируется неправильно patch_3 особенно криво,
то JQuery выдает ошибку после чего

> Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

то если количество точек меньше у arr_point_end чем у arr_now_point
выдает ошибку

> Cannot read property 'curve' of undefined

Если вдруг кому то это интересно можете доработать мой код.
Потому что я уже навряд ли что нибудь могу здесь сделать.

Comment: что делает этот код?

Comment: @Grundy занимает много места :)

Comment: если к примеру сделать`width="580"`  `viewBox="0 0 2000 2000"` то там даже появляются какие то рисуночки

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Код с 1 по 414 строку это копируемые мной функций из староних источников. я не смог вставить его как ссылку.

Comment: @Grundy Это код деформаций svg файла в вопросе есть ссылка на  [codepe](https://codepen.io/zeni-agentt/pen/yLNggZQ) с наглядным примером по идеи код должен работать таким вот образом     [up/off-down/off](https://codepen.io/zeni-agentt/pen/YzXPOzw), [up/on-dodn/on](https://codepen.io/zeni-agentt/pen/WNvbzvx)

Answer (score 1):

Причин неработоспособности вашего приложения несколько и вам об этом система сообщает:

**1. Неподходящие друг другу `path` для плавного морфинга от одной фигуры к другой.**

Явный признак этого, - скачкообразная анимация без промежуточных положений, либо её вообще не будет.

Чтобы избежать этого недостаточно просто сделать одинаковое количество  узловых точек в обоих `path` но ещё необходимо, чтобы :

> Команды `С, Q, T, S, A` кривых Безье должны быть одинаковыми в одинаковых по
>   счёту узлах,  пути не должны  иметь разрывов,  контуры в каждой фигуре
>   должны быть  одинарными.

Для реализации этих требований используется техника, подробно описанная в этом топике:

[Плавный морфинг одного path в другой path](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1052728/28748)

Это самый сложный этап, но если потратите время и освоите его, то с морфингом у вас никогда не будет проблем.  Пробуйте, у людей всё получилось сделать с первого раза.

Имея работоспособные `path` уже не будет никаких проблем с их анимацией, либо с помощью `SMIL SVG`, либо используя различные фреймворки.

[Вот ссылка и примеры моего ответа на EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59994644/7394871)

*Пример анимации с помощью SMILL:*

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   
     width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >  
 <style>
  path {
  fill:dodgerblue;
    }
 </style>
 
<path  d="m268.3 164.3c0 31.4-12.6 59.9-33 80.7-20.9 21.2-49.9 34.4-82 34.4-31.5 0-60.1-12.7-80.9-33.3-21.1-20.9-34.1-49.8-34.1-81.8 0-31.1 12.3-59.3 32.4-80 20.9-21.6 50.2-35.1 82.7-35.1 32.3 0 61.6 13.3 82.5 34.8 20.2 20.7 32.6 49 32.6 80.2z">
   <animate attributeName="d"
     begin="0s"
  dur="5s"
  values="
          m268.3 164.3c0 31.4-12.6 59.9-33 80.7-20.9 21.2-49.9 34.4-82 34.4-31.5 0-60.1-12.7-80.9-33.3-21.1-20.9-34.1-49.8-34.1-81.8 0-31.1 12.3-59.3 32.4-80 20.9-21.6 50.2-35.1 82.7-35.1 32.3 0 61.6 13.3 82.5 34.8 20.2 20.7 32.6 49 32.6 80.2z;
       m268.3 164.3c0 31.4 0 86.7 0 115.1-26.6 0-82.9 0-115.1 0-31.5 0-73.4 0-114.2 0-0.9-26.3-0.9-83.1-0.9-115.1 0-31.1 0-87 0-115.1 26 0 82.6 0 115.1 0 32.3 0 91.9 0 115.1 0.9 0 30.9 0 83 0 114.2z;
        m268.3 164.3c0 31.4-12.6 59.9-33 80.7-20.9 21.2-49.9 34.4-82 34.4-31.5 0-60.1-12.7-80.9-33.3-21.1-20.9-34.1-49.8-34.1-81.8 0-31.1 12.3-59.3 32.4-80 20.9-21.6 50.2-35.1 82.7-35.1 32.3 0 61.6 13.3 82.5 34.8 20.2 20.7 32.6 49 32.6 80.2z;"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    fill="freeze"  />   
    
 </path> 

</svg>
```

*Пример анимации с помощью `animeJS` в принципе она делает тоже самое, что `SMIL`*

```js
const circlePath = 'm268.3 164.3c0 31.4-12.6 59.9-33 80.7-20.9 21.2-49.9 34.4-82 34.4-31.5 0-60.1-12.7-80.9-33.3-21.1-20.9-34.1-49.8-34.1-81.8 0-31.1 12.3-59.3 32.4-80 20.9-21.6 50.2-35.1 82.7-35.1 32.3 0 61.6 13.3 82.5 34.8 20.2 20.7 32.6 49 32.6 80.2z';
const squarePath = 'm268.3 164.3c0 31.4 0 86.7 0 115.1-26.6 0-82.9 0-115.1 0-31.5 0-73.4 0-114.2 0-0.9-26.3-0.9-83.1-0.9-115.1 0-31.1 0-87 0-115.1 26 0 82.6 0 115.1 0 32.3 0 91.9 0 115.1 0.9 0 30.9 0 83 0 114.2z';

var timeline = anime.timeline({
  autoplay: true,
  direction: "alternate",
  loop: true
});

timeline.add({
  targets: ".shape",
  d: {
    value: [
      circlePath,
      squarePath
    ],
    duration: 1500,
    easing: "easeInOutQuad"
  },
  offset: 500
});
```

```css
svg {
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 300 300;" xml:space="preserve">
  <path class="shape" fill="blue" d="m268.3 164.3c0 31.4-12.6 59.9-33 80.7-20.9 21.2-49.9 34.4-82 34.4-31.5 0-60.1-12.7-80.9-33.3-21.1-20.9-34.1-49.8-34.1-81.8 0-31.1 12.3-59.3 32.4-80 20.9-21.6 50.2-35.1 82.7-35.1 32.3 0 61.6 13.3 82.5 34.8 20.2 20.7 32.6 49 32.6 80.2z"/>
</svg>
```

Кроме `animeJS` анимацию плавного морфинга можно так же сделать и с помощью
   [snapJS](http://snapsvg.io/),  [svgJS](https://svgjs.com/docs/3.0/),  [kute](https://github.com/thednp/kute.js), [flubber](https://github.com/veltman/flubber#alternatives), [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap/) и конечно с помощью нативного `Javascript` и `jQuery`.

**Поэтому вывод:**

*Неважно какой вы выберите фреймворк, важно сделать качественные `path`*

Без выполнения данного условия никакая волшебная палочка, в виде крутого фреймворка не выручит, не заставит работать анимацию.

Comment: Я уже рассматривал различные фреймворки. И не нашел никакого способа контролировать сам морф. Я имею в веду что они лишь создают плавную анимацию между двумя морфами.  Я не смогу сделать нечто подобное  [up/off-down/off](https://codepen.io/zeni-agentt/pen/YzXPOzw) [up/on-down/on](https://codepen.io/zeni-agentt/pen/WNvbzvx). Потому что фреймворки создают не морф а просто анимацию. и единственное что я могу сделать это контролировать скорость анимаций .[MorphSVG](https://codepen.io/zeni-agentt/pen/zYGYdZG) В них нет способа смешивать два разных морфа.