# Как сделать плавную анимацию контура овала?

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg, svg-animation, анимация

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такой элемент + такую анимацию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `canvas || SVG`...

Comment: а если курсор осановить внутри - анимация будет дальше продолжаться ?

Comment: Ждёмс еще ответов более точных. :)

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов Сашку ждём ? Или надо пояснить откуда я всё это взял ?

Comment: @MaximLensky нет не надо ничего пояснить.Я тоже хотель  год назад сделать такую анимации как на гиф проста как всегда поленился.По этому было бы отлично увидеть реализацию  ответа как на гиф.(желательно без svg)

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов а я вот не знаю как остановить анимацию когда выхожу за пределы path

Comment: @MaximLensky Js в студию

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов path.onmouseout нее работает, разумеется что переменную path я объявлял и если так пишу то анимация дёргаться начинает ..что мне не нравится

Comment: @MaximLensky да видно что то не доработано.Но к сожалению в SVG я не разбираюсь чтобы точно сказать что и как это исправить.

Comment: @MaximLensky "Максимка" - что за фамильярность - (Сашку ждём )?? Мне, по крайней мере, так не нравится

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  тут проблемы с интернетом, когда вернусь поговорим, но написал я не со зла

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Не точное совпадение но делается это так**

```html
<svg viewBox="0 100 200 200" width="500">

  <path d="m 177.64882,197.97025 c 0,37.99259 -34.43744,68.79166 -76.91816,68.79166 -42.480725,0 -69.159579,-31.59971 -76.91816,-68.79166 -5.381144,-25.79534 24.948217,-47.28279 76.91816,-68.79167 39.25182,-16.24521 76.91816,30.79908 76.91816,68.79167 z" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1">
             <animate 
            attributeName="d"
            values="m 177.64882,197.97025 c 0,37.99259 -34.43744,68.79166 -76.91816,68.79166 -42.480725,0 -69.159579,-31.59971 -76.91816,-68.79166 -5.381144,-25.79534 24.948217,-47.28279 76.91816,-68.79167 39.25182,-16.24521 76.91816,30.79908 76.91816,68.79167 z;M 184.45239,225.94049 C 173.03174,278.83237 67.074145,275.70093 40.254469,255.8006 26.83666,245.84452 -5.7594918,188.00429 17.764881,173.02382 59.881982,146.20338 79.246735,139.07933 123.78721,131.44644 c 97.53788,-16.71505 68.22409,59.48688 60.66518,94.49405 z;m 177.64882,197.97025 c -0.35166,37.99096 -34.43744,68.79166 -76.91816,68.79166 -42.480725,0 -69.15947,-31.59973 -76.91816,-68.79166 -5.381253,-25.79548 15.606755,-78.27985 76.91816,-68.79167 42.69554,6.6073 77.21723,36.48143 76.91816,68.79167 z;m 177.64882,197.97025 c -27.05429,33.14413 -44.89336,66.81351 -76.91816,68.79166 -42.399915,2.61901 -69.15947,-31.59973 -76.91816,-68.79166 -5.381253,-25.79548 15.83044,-57.95634 76.91816,-68.79167 47.98717,-8.51164 99.56499,41.04711 76.91816,68.79167 z;m 177.64882,197.97025 c -11.42065,52.89188 -50.09848,88.69199 -76.91816,68.79166 -13.417809,-9.95608 -60.451612,-46.28248 -76.91816,-68.79166 -18.7497411,-25.63023 9.949479,-74.61404 99.97471,-66.52381 98.56255,8.85745 61.42052,31.51664 53.86161,66.52381 z ;m 177.64882,197.97025 c -11.42065,52.89188 -43.52204,68.65952 -76.91816,68.79166 -42.439949,0.16792 -64.905386,-56.60574 -76.91816,-68.79166 -19.2149502,-19.4919 15.20879,-73.7357 76.91816,-68.79167 98.64366,7.90312 84.47707,33.7845 76.91816,68.79167 z;m 177.64882,197.97025 c 0,37.99259 -34.43744,68.79166 -76.91816,68.79166 -42.480725,0 -69.159579,-31.59971 -76.91816,-68.79166 -5.381144,-25.79534 24.948217,-47.28279 76.91816,-68.79167 39.25182,-16.24521 76.91816,30.79908 76.91816,68.79167 z"
            dur="4s"
            begin="mousemove"
            repeatCount="indefinite"/>   
    
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Danielqwaqwaqwa это всё равно не правильно

Answer (score 4):

> подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такой элемент + такую анимацию

В этом топике очень подробно, с картинками рассказывается, как делается это:

[Плавный морфинг одного path в другой path](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1052728/28748)

Анимация начинается /заканчивается при наведении курсора на овал.
При наведении на текст - анимация тени надписи: **Explore HOTEL**

```
 begin="oval.mouseover"
  end="oval.mouseout"
   repeatCount="4"
     dur="5s"
```

Ниже полный код:

```css
.container {
width: 50vw;
height:50vh;
}
 #txt1 {

  fill:gray;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.4s; 
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  
}

 #txt1:hover {
    fill:white;
 pointer-events:fill;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9, 0 3px 0 #bbb, 0 4px 0 #b9b9b9, 0 5px 0 #aaa, 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 transform: scale(1.5);
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" >

  <path id="oval" d="m380.5 199.3c0 26.4-4.7 59.3-29.6 71.6-36.8 18.2-39.9 17.3-69 27.6-24.1 8.6-53.3 14.7-81.2 21.2-28.3 6.6-45.5 5.7-75.5 7.9-30.7 2.2-47.3 7-77.4-7.8-26-12.8-31-19.5-31-46.9 0-25.1 12.2-55.1 29.2-75 18.8-22 51-65.9 81.7-94.9 16.7-15.7 24.8-23.5 71.8-34.4 50.8-11.8 55.2 4.7 79.1 13.1 29.6 10.4 54.7 26.4 72.5 46.2 18.6 20.5 29.3 45 29.3 71.3z" fill="transparent" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="5" cursor="pointer">
             <animate 
            attributeName="d"
            values="
   m380.5 199.3c0 26.4-4.7 59.3-29.6 71.6-36.8 18.2-39.9 17.3-69 27.6-24.1 8.6-53.3 14.7-81.2 21.2-28.3 6.6-45.5 5.7-75.5 7.9-30.7 2.2-47.3 7-77.4-7.8-26-12.8-31-19.5-31-46.9 0-25.1 12.2-55.1 29.2-75 18.8-22 51-65.9 81.7-94.9 16.7-15.7 24.8-23.5 71.8-34.4 50.8-11.8 55.2 4.7 79.1 13.1 29.6 10.4 54.7 26.4 72.5 46.2 18.6 20.5 29.3 45 29.3 71.3z;
   
   m378.1 222.6c0 26.4-4.7 59.3-29.6 71.6-36.8 18.2-35.1 15.5-67.2 17.4-25.6 1.6-53.3-28.4-81.2-21.9-28.3 6.6-44.9 35.7-74.9 37.8-30.7 2.2-46.7-44.5-76.8-59.3-26-12.8-31-19.5-31-46.9 0-25.1 23-29.4 40-49.3 18.8-22 9-40.8 39.8-69.7 16.7-15.7 57.2 11.3 104.2 0.3 50.8-11.8 53.4-29.4 77.3-21.1 29.6 10.4 27.1 61.8 45 81.6 18.6 20.5 54.5 33 54.5 59.3z;
   
   m382.3 169.3c0 26.4-23.7 11.1-29.6 71.6-1 10.1 38 112.4-74.9 30.6-20.8-15-76 53.1-104 59.6-28.3 6.6-34.1-35-64.1-32.9-30.7 2.2-34.2-2.5-61.2-29.9-20.3-20.6 11.5-53.6 11.5-81 0-25.1-13-39 4-58.9 18.8-22 56.4 19.8 87.1-9.2 16.7-15.7 2.7-26.5 49.6-37.4 50.8-11.8 55.2 22.1 79.1 30.5 29.6 10.4 19.8 7.9 48-2.3 26-9.4 54.5 33 54.5 59.3z;
   
   m380.5 199.3c0 26.4-4.7 59.3-29.6 71.6-36.8 18.2-39.9 17.3-69 27.6-24.1 8.6-53.3 14.7-81.2 21.2-28.3 6.6-45.5 5.7-75.5 7.9-30.7 2.2-47.3 7-77.4-7.8-26-12.8-31-19.5-31-46.9 0-25.1 12.2-55.1 29.2-75 18.8-22 51-65.9 81.7-94.9 16.7-15.7 24.8-23.5 71.8-34.4 50.8-11.8 55.2 4.7 79.1 13.1 29.6 10.4 54.7 26.4 72.5 46.2 18.6 20.5 29.3 45 29.3 71.3z"
   
            begin="oval.mouseover"
   end="oval.mouseout"
            repeatCount="4"
   dur="5s"/> 
         <animate attributeName="stroke" dur="5s" begin="oval.mouseover" end="oval.mouseout" values = "red;dodgerblue;green;gold;red" repeatCount="10" />   
    
  </path>  
    <text id="txt1" font-size="24px" x="220" y="50%"  text-anchor="middle"  >Explore HOTEL</text> 
</svg>
</div>
```